# Merge Intel Fortran compiler tags: [ifort], [intel-visual-fortran] and [intel-fortran]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are several tags referring to Intel's Fortran compiler:

- [ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifort): 189 questions;
- [intel-visual-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-visual-fortran): 30;
- [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran): 11.

This seems a little unnecessary. Should these tags be merged? [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran) has perhaps the most useful wiki.

Further, should those tags be removed from questions which are clearly not specific to the compiler?

Or even, as the Fortran community here is so small should we just remove all of them (adding [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) where that isn't already there)?

Possibly one may even consider [compaq-visual-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compaq-visual-fortran) (6 questions) here also: IVF [is the successor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/migrating-from-compaq-visual-fortran) to CVF.

Comment: [tag:compaq-visual-fortran] all empty.

Comment: @davidism: I don't know what you used to edit those tags, but any post that contains quotes has been f'd-up by your edits, since you seem to have replaced all quotes with html entities. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26321265/revisions).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198063/merge-ifort-and-intel-visual-fortran and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197203/which-fortran-tags-should-i-use

Comment: @davidism Please stop ruining posts! Code isn't compilable any more once you changed the single quotes...

Comment: @davidism rollback your changes and retag the questions properly!!! I started to rollback that, but I realized you break too many of them, please repair them or we will have to ask a moderator to do that automatically.

Comment: I sincerely apologize to all of you for the trouble.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284919/replaced-with-quot-in-edit/284933#284933

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, merge them.  Yes, make `intel-fortran` the sole survivor.  Yes, include `compaq-visual-fortran` in the merge.  Yes, remove unwarranted tags.

No, don't merge them all into `fortran`, compiler-specific variants may be a plague, but we have to work with them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes on merging the intel fortran tags.

On intel visual fortran/parallel studio merge them into intel-fortran, and yes merge cvf in( intel visual fortran is the successor to compaq visual fortran - ide's using visual studio on windows, fortran studio/parallel studio either use visual studio on windows or eclipse on linux)

Definitely no, on merging them all into fortran.
Fortran compilers are way to different on flags/options to do that.
Especially on older fortran (66/77) code where getting the right selection of flags with current compilers makes the differences between segfaults/bsod's etc and successful compilation.

If they were merged you would end up polluting the fortran tag with ide/os specific topics that have nothing to do with standard fortran.

Answer (score 3):

Intel-fortran should be the main tag but ifort should be a tag **synonym**.  As results above show, ifort was used 17 times more often than intel-fortran.

Although intel-fortran is a better tag name, many people will look for ifort and fail to find it because if you type the first few letters of "ifort" you will not be offered "intel-fortran" as an option.  And that's exactly what most people will initially do.  Why make this tag harder to find than is necessary?

And relatedly, there is "gfortran" but no "gnu-fortran".  It would also be nice to have those be synonyms.

Comment: I tried to propose the suggested synonym, but failed, lacking one or more of: nous, score or privilege.

Comment: I agree now I've more experience that a synonym may have been a good idea.  We can't do that now [tag:ifort] doesn't exist, and I'm not sure it's worth tagging a question just to immediately synonymize.  To a degree we want searching for "ifort" as a tag to fail: [tag:fortran] should be the first choice and once it is visible through there any curation-minded user can add appropriate tags.  Do we think there's a big group of potential answerers missing Intel Fortran questions because of `[intel-fortran] -[fortran]`?

Comment: Admittedly, there are questions about ifort which are not about Fortran, but I think [tag:fortran] is quiet enough that those questions cause little harm and would be quickly retagged.

Comment: And: aah, a nice reminder of the time of the great HTML enborkening.  (See comments on question.)

Comment: @francescalus Maybe I don't understand how tags work, but isn't it just equivalent to an alias or pointer?  E.g. "ifort" would not be a tag, only a synonym making it easier to find "intel-fortran"?

Comment: @francescalus  I certainly don't think this is a huge problem and certainly agree that we would almost always want a question to be tagged "fortran" rather than "ifort" or "gfortran" if it were a binary choice.  But I think a pretty big portion of fortran questions should probably be tagged with either "ifort" or "gfortran" **in addition to** the "fortran" tag.

Comment: @francescalus FWIW, I failed to use "intel-fortran" as a tag on a couple of occasions because I didn't know it existed after I initially looked for an "ifort" tag.  Again, I'm not suggesting it's a huge problem.  I also would use the tag more after realizing that it is the recommended tag for dec/hp/compaq fortran, which I (unfortunately) am still using ;-)

Comment: To be a synonym it would need to exist as a real tag.  One way we tried to help with finding compiler tags was linking in the [tag:fortran] tag wiki.  Greater visibility of that information for new users is perhaps another problem.  That said, if you don't tag a specific compiler, that's not really a problem for visibility.  Even if, say, vendors look only at "their" tags, we normal users can quickly retag.  (I do agree correct/good tagging important. )

Comment: @francescalus  OK, thanks for the explanation tho I have to admit that I don't really understand why it would be hard to create a tag ifort & then make it a synonym for intel-fortran.  I literally don't know the process except that there is a page to suggest synonyms but I don't have any "intel-fortran" rep so I can't do it myself.