# Replaced " with &quot; in edit

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I do not understand the edit made on my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22328191/revisions ([direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22328191/5))

If it is a retagging job, why have the quotes been changed? (It even does not work in the code section.)

Comment: That's actually an invalid edit o.O

Comment: Maybe some quirk of their browser, or a script, or an external editor, that replaces all quotation marks with their respective html entity. In any case, why not simply roll back, apply the tag yourself, and possibly leave a comment for them? =)

Comment: I rolled back the quotes already, and re-applied the tag edit.

Comment: It seems he's doing this with some sort of script - the edits are coming *way* too fast. He's corrupted hundreds of posts.

Comment: I have flagged for moderator attention. The clean-up work will be huge...

Comment: Pinged a mod on the meta.SE tavern too: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2980085#2980085 Not really the best way to get this handled, but at least this raises awareness for what's probably a broken editing tool.

Comment: It looks like a script that achieved self-consciousness and is now running rampant.

Comment: We've recently been doing a lot of burnination work and to try and help this along, davidism wrote a bot to do edits, which obviously failed -_- davidism has now gone to bed and so will wake up to a lovely message from balpha in the morning. He had the best interests of the community at heart, but obviously he has made a mistake and will face up to the consequences.

Comment: There's a few members of the Python room who would like to help clean up, but we will wait for any mods to say "yes" unless they want to do it automatically. I'd like to apologise on my friends behalf for now, and am sure he'll profusely apologise later.

Comment: One of the devs has been made aware of this by @J. Steen's flag and has notified the author of the script. No idea how the edits will be sorted out though.

Comment: Based on a conversation with balpha in the Tavern we've began cleaning everything up. We're obviously keeping the re-tagging in as that was fine/worked, but are removing problematic things like `&quot;`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

My sincere apologies to you and everyone else for the trouble I've caused.  I decided to use a script without testing and obviously was wrong to do that.  Thanks to the efforts of everyone in chat, this is now fixed.

[image: davidism: "web developer"]

---

For future potential &quot;web developers&quot;, this specific problem was caused because I didn't use an [unsafe filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) in the API, so it escaped the markdown body which I then resubmitted.

Comment: *I decided to use a script without testing and obviously was wrong to do that*  And you did so in public in front of an enormous community of your programming peers !  Big up for admitting it.  (And a down for doing it in the first place, net effect 0.)

Comment: Awesome. Good job clearing it up again. And kudos on the image. ;)

Comment: So it didn't quite work out - but kudos for attempting to do something pro-active about all the burniation requests knocking around...hope you fix it up and keep using it!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) might help (or maybe not).

Comment: If you want to look at it from a glass half full perspective, consider that you've supplied the edit audit mechanism will loads of new content. :)