# What causes you to abandon an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, se-quality-project

I'm working on that last queue that we'll be adding to `/review` as part of the quality project, and it's arguably the most interesting piece of the puzzle.

It's a queue where folks that are interested in helping (mostly) new users can go to work on questions that the community has deemed likely to be valuable, but in need of some improvement before they can become lasting artifacts on the site. These are the questions that were sorted as *'should be improved'* from the new [triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage).

The scope of what you can do in this new queue still hasn't settled, but editing is going to be a *major* part of it. One of the best ways you can help someone new to the site that asks what *could* be an interesting question is to edit it for them, and let them know *why* you changed what you did in the summary. This new queue will *very* strongly suggest substantive edits, since the questions that land in it have been marked by multiple users as needing some help.

Speaking to that, I'd like to get some feedback from anyone that has spent time editing. Once you're in the editor, what can cause you to abandon your edit? From experience, and the limited reasons I can infer, the following things can cause it:

1. Turns out, you just don't have enough time.
2. There's not enough information given - you can't really improve it without a missing piece, but you didn't realize it was missing when you started.
3. You had a thought on how you were going to edit when you clicked the button, but it escaped you once the editor loaded. You just can't make sense of it after all.
4. As you started cleaning things up, you realize it's a duplicate, and went to find the duplicate instead.
5. You just lose enthusiasm somehow. Maybe it was more work than you thought it would be. Maybe it turned out to not be that great of a question after all; the cost-to-reward ratio just didn't pan out.

Editing can be funny that way, you often don't know what you've bitten off until you've chewed it for a bit.

Even if you closely identify with one of the reasons I've listed, I'd like to hear from you. Any narrative you care to share will help lend insight into (1) the selection process for what gets shown to you first when you enter the queue and (2) ways that the system can possibly alleviate some of the common pains that editors feel.

Your responses will help us put together an interface for the queue that gets out of your way as you help gems 'in the rough' take on a shine, while making sure the tools we provide you for doing that are extremely optimized for *your* time.

<sub>This post is part of the Stack Exchange quality project ([More on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) | [More on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project))</sub>

Comment: Or I spend a long time on an edit that makes a lot of changes, and then the OP edits the question substantially and I don't want to spend all that time making the changes again. Sort of a mix between 1 and 5 on your list.

Comment: I agree that the biggest problem is the concurrent edit.  However, if a question has been through the triage queue and into a second review/editing queue, then the initial hubbub has long since died down.  Of course, there'll be some contention in the new 'improve queue', especially to start with, and I think that you'll need to consider (carefully!) how to handle that.  It would be even more frustrating to spend time improving an answer only to have the effort ignored.  OTOH, you don't want someone to lock it indefinitely.  You need some timely way of telling when they've abandoned an edit.

Comment: I don't know if you can use JavaScript to check in every 5 minutes or so while someone is doing the editing, asking for confirmation.  Or if you can tell that they're at work.  Even that could be a bit of a nuisance; if I go to find the manual and it takes me more than 5 minutes (because I had to help a child with homework, or I couldn't find the book), I could lose the effort put in.  Would there be a method of saving the edit buffer?  Would it be that the JavaScript would notify you that you may have lost priority in the queue after 5 minutes of inactivity?  Tricky, tricky stuff!

Comment: 100% concurent edits. Well, before I had character limit, it was sometimes also the fact that the edit turned out to be too minor.

Comment: All of your suggestions, except 3. Quite often 5, unfortunately.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I’m not sure if any monitoring via JS would work OK for me. I use [It’s All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) Firefox addon to be able to edit using Vim. Cut & paste into one’s favorite editor is essentially equivalent. Don’t know how common such a behavior is, maybe I’ll have to cope with a little discomfort.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is covered by point (5), but some posts are formatted so poorly I cannot read them.  If, after a few minutes of editing a post I read it back and realize it's crap, I'll abandon the edits (probably down vote/possibly vote to close).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There will be some sort of mutual exclusion from within the queue itself - no two people would be shown the same question to work on. Feedback here also indicates that it's pretty important to block 'outside' noise as well, or folks happening upon posts in the queue opportunistically from outside of the queue. I don't  think that will be common, but I am going to account for it, even if to say 'edits from within the improvement queue always win' if there's contention.

Comment: Lock for the question I am editing? Finally!

Comment: Sometimes I plan to edit the question, but after I've opened the editor, I realize that I _can_ fix the question, but because of a complete lack of effort, I don't feel like he "deserves" to be helped.

Comment: What I hate most:  _Community♦ reviewed this so_me date at ti:me: Reject_

Comment: My boss walking past...

Comment: Usually because I almost finish the edit and then realise that I read the question wrong in the first place.

Comment: 6) I want to see what markup was used to achieve certain output.  Never intended to make an edit, but had to open the editor to see

Comment: When I realize I have not had enough coffee yet.

Comment: 5. Sometimes I'm just too lazy to even fini

Comment: List the abandoned edits by OS and browser and look for patterns. Then speak to a web developer - there are smart ones -  about it: they capture all the session information they can on abandoned purchasing dialogs, because anything that doesn't fail at the final hurdle of payment approval is almost always an error in the web page. Typically a popup that didn't display, or froze the page - or the user's instinctive backspace keystroke to correct a spelling error navigating off the page and losing all the information in the form. That kind of thing, even if it isn't that specific glitch.

Comment: I realize I'm just polishing a turd.

Comment: For me: - a reformatting edit turns out to have more code than expected (vertical scroll), - somebody else did a edit, - i just realized the edit would be too substantial. For all of those i try to cancel the edit, but sometimes I just happen to browse away while researching it.

Comment: When the rest of the question is completely fine except it's missing code tags. As they only count as two characters it isn't enough to allow you to edit.

At this point you're struck with a dilemma, cancel the edit, or try to nitpick through the rest of the question to find punctuation to add JUST to break the cap and allow the edit through.

Answer (score 199):

I'll abandon an edit when I realize that a post isn't worth editing.

I'll often start editing a post as soon as I see that it has an error (poor formatting, excess/intros, etc.), but as I'm editing, I realize that there's either an overwhelming amount of problems, or the question is just bad/should be closed.

**No point in polishing a turd...**

Comment: ... and then quickly move to nominating to close.

Comment: Hmm, likewise. Much like how I sometimes start to answer, but then realise the question is incomplete.

Comment: hopefully such questions will have been pruned out as unsalvageable by the triage queue

Answer (score 169):

The most common reason for me to abandon an edit: someone else edited the same question faster than me, and fixed what I wanted to fix.

Comment: Was going to post this too, so will just add that "and fixed what I wanted to fix" isn't always true: sometimes the faster editor changed different parts of the post, and I don't have time to start merging the edits, thus just leaving it all behind. :/

Comment: Wishlist: Git-style edit merge feature when there are two conflicting edits and both are useful (and edit different parts).

Comment: @matsjoyce Even better: real-time collaborative editing fields.

Comment: @Bergi how would you revision that?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Like crazy :-) No idea, probably some kind of multiple editors for the revision entry (like we have multiple voters for a close decision, and with percentages like community wiki posts).

Comment: @ColeJohnson follow Google Drive's style of saying multiple people worked on the same revision

Comment: Yep, I had the same first thoughts as answerer and commenters. I clean up formatting and typos, click to save and `can't save, post has been edited by OP/someone else` even though my and their edits would merge beautifully. Either git-style merging or Google Docs style _I see my fellow editors cursor do their thing_ would be wonderful :)

Comment: Yes, this. Outside of this scenario, which is a very specific use-case in Stack Overflow some wiki sites that are devoted to factual advice, the commonest reason for a user to abandon an interaction is repeated UI failures on the web page.

Comment: Damm [sonic](https://www.google.com/search?q=gotta+go+fast&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 124):

I'll abandon an edit when I've started taking the time to improve it and I get the message that someone else has edited it and mine will only be accepted, if it is greater than theirs.  Often times, I'll cancel my edit, see they didn't correct everything, but I will stop editing because I might continue to bump into other edits.

Basically, edit conflicts are the main reason why I'll abandon an edit.

Comment: This. Lack of some sort of a locking system is my biggest turn-off from editing as well - *especially* when a lot of time and thought would be needed.

Comment: It would be very nice if there were a way to *merge* edits similar to branch merging in git.

Comment: It would be nice to supersede/ignore/override pending revisions with an edit of your own if you already have 2000+ rep, or if you have a gold badge for revisions, or if you have a gold badge for reviewing suggested edits, or... etc.

Comment: @TylerH Don't 2000 rep users already have the option to overwrite pending sub-2000 rep users' edits with their own? I've seen it before in my rejected edits.

Comment: @Celeo After thinking about it a bit, I think the answer is technically "yes", but I'm not entirely sure. If I "improve" someone else's edit before me (e.g. I click "edit" and someone else's suggested edit pops up in a review queue modal), does that auto-approve the edit unilaterally? Or does my improvement count as one "approve" vote and then the other reviews will then vote to approve/reject my new, improved edit?

Comment: @TylerH It approves unilaterally. The thinking is that, if you're putting in the effort to make your own edit, then you're looking at things closely enough to be able to decide if it's a good edit.

Answer (score 85):

Edit is for a simple typo but the dreaded

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

appears.

Lost count of the number of posts I've seen with a single eye catching typo gone unfixed for *years* because no other changes are required.

Comment: Right after the typo, you could add `(FTFY)`, that gets you to the required number of characters...

Comment: Add some extra spaces somewhere. :)

Comment: I understand this isn't exactly a "solution," but once you've made it to 2000 reputation, you can make any kind of edit you'd like. There's no use in giving you 2 rep for fixing one character, and I'm assuming that this queue will only be open to those with editing privileges, as it would be a bit silly to ask people to edit posts from one queue and then send them over to *another* queue for approval.

Comment: @pgr: You jest, but someone out there is going to do exactly that, and do it unironically.

Comment: @AstroCB, but I'm not editing to get 2 points (and really, what does that matter to SO anyway? It's not like it's coming out of a bank account or something). I'm editing to fix a glaring error in post and improve the quality of the site. The length of characters shouldn't make any difference. However, if that 2 points is really that big of a deal, then why not remove the editing limit, but just stipulate that any edit under 10 characters doesn't get any points? That way, the site improves, but they don't have to worry about giving away any of their precious 2 points for a small edit.

Comment: "How to write an infinite loop in C?" Ans: `while()`. --> Edit it to `while(1);` --> Edit gets rejected --> so edit it to `while(1);  // Adding this utterly useless comment for after all the tall tales that SO tells about being a clutter-free Q&A site, it won't let me fix a simple problem without adding this clutter.` That should do.

Comment: This is a big one for me, and the nonsense "just edit something else" argument... I long for the day where I have 2K and don't have to deal with it anymore. Maybe the _"Must contain 6 characters"_ limit could be elevated for 500 or 1K users? Keeping the review requirement until 2K.

Comment: I often came across great posts where I had no idea what I could improve. Just that there was one typo: E.g. a variable which was called `initialise` one time and `initialize` a second time in a source code example. I don't want to know how much time I've spent on finding these kind of errors when copy-and-pasting them. And when I wanted to save others from having the same problem, I just couldn't. This bothered me for the next couple of minutes until I went on. This is by far one of the most annoying restrictions of SO.

Comment: This is especially infuriating after fixing a broken link that only needs a few characters to fix, e.g., because a site's structure changed.

Comment: @ouflak Agreed; I'm just giving what the standard SE response is to these sorts of complaints.

Comment: @funkwurm, I know how you feel. I'd like to think I'm 400 something points away from caring. But I consider myself a technical editor of professional level. I'm made to wonder if the people who put this restriction in place have really had to edit anything at all where clarity was of the upmost vital importance and even the most subtle of changes/grammatical corrections could make all the difference technically, legally, and compliance-wise. Because of my nature and experience, this is going to bug me for a long time I think.

Comment: Maybe having one-character edits not be attributed (eg: name shown under the answer) would be a good answer to that

Comment: @Dorian hah, is that the reason it won't let me do that? :P I will happily not get credit/rep for a 2 character edit. I edit because it makes my eye twitch, not for some personal gain.

Comment: So [this meta-SO answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251618/2684660) explains why the limit exists in the first place. Ok, what if < 6 char edits from 1K users don't need reviewing? Or get reviewed by the asker? What if < 6 char edits don't bump the question to the front-page? Could the system be smart enough to recognize that 4 spaces to get the last line of code also into the code-block can't possibly do harm to the question? Some combination of the above?

Comment: @AstroCB With the current size of the stackexchange network you need over 200k reputation evenly distributed over your accounts to edit everywhere.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That may be true, but this question is about the forthcoming review queue, which, again, I'm assuming won't be available to people who don't have editing privileges in the first place.

Comment: Just saw this example of what happens if `< 6 char edits` are not allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1028993/1202500 --> two comments distracting the user from the "real" comments (or was the edit function introduced not until later? - anyway, this still happens nowadays, just that I don't have an example of it atm)

Comment: @ouflak - A workaround is to add `&nbsp;` to pad things out. [example here](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/221798/revisions)

Comment: IIRC you can just delete a word and then re-write it yourself. Or make an edit that adds "many thanks!" and then edit it again immediately to fix the typo and then remove the "many thanks!". Doing that within a five minute window will only count as one revision but may be able to bypass the 6 character rule.

Comment: @TylerH the edits need to be reviewed though so adding gratuitous additional pleasantries like "many thanks" will probably not pass review.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, I was talking about for people over 2k, I guess.

Comment: @TylerH they don't get the minimum length restriction anyway do they?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not sure. I haven't edited anything short in a while. If not, then I guess my comment would be irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, ran into this the other day when I tried to reformat some pasted code in the question so it wasn't just one hard-to-read jumbled line of program code (multiple statements on one line separated by semi-colons), but since the combination of carriage returns I added to do so didn't add up to more than six characters it would not let me.

Comment: @MaskedMan I would reject that edit as "clearly conflicts with author's intent".

Comment: @Gothdo You are free to do what you want, it doesn't really concern me.

Answer (score 56):

Beyond the obvious situation where another edit has been made while I was attempting improvement on the post (and my own efforts are likely to be discarded), the two primary reasons for abandoning an edit would seem to be:

1. While I initially thought I could contribute some legibility to the post, once involved in the actual edit process I come to realize that the post is FUBAR. A comprehensive edit would demand a complete rewrite and that should be the OP's responsibility. Abandon edit, down-vote and leave comment.
2. When terminology is just plain wrong or used in the wrong context, edits to make content relevant start creeping up on the *Attempts to reply* category. I might think I know what the OP was trying to express with the misuse of industry 'buzz-words' but it isn't my place to start changing the overall flavour of the question. At some point, a grey area turns into crossing the line and I abandon the edit.

Answer (score 30):

I'll abandon an edit when the OP has huge formatting problems in their question, but I start hitting edit conflicts because they are editing their question every few seconds (and still ignoring the awful formatting).

Sometimes it's not worth it to wait until they settle down, so it's a mix of #1 and #5.

Comment: ".. and still ignoring the awful formatting .." Had that yesterday. After the fourth-or-so I felt [like this](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/000/578/1234931504682.jpg).

Answer (score 29):

I'm a big fan of editing.

Like, [a huge fan](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit).

I think it's amazing what community collaboration can do in a place like this, where the people who are answering the questions actually have the ability to make the question better. So the fact that we'll have an entire queue essentially dedicated to editing is great.

Well, except for one thing. The key part of what I just said is this:

> ...**the people who are answering the questions** actually have the ability to make the question better.

The most common way for people to edit something is to come across on their own while roaming the site. So, if they're already at the post, they likely know *something* about the topic and are able to improve the question or answer to make it clearer to others who don't.

When you give people posts to edit in a queue, you're asking them to edit something that they wouldn't have necessarily come across on their own, so it's likely to be something that they're not familiar about.

For most cases, this is fine; fixing common grammatical errors and making posts readable is typically a fairly mundane process (in fact, that's why I created the linked project above in the first place). However, I've found that the biggest thing that stops me from making in-depth edits is not understanding entirely what the question is about.

For that reason, I think it would be a good idea to allow tag filtering in the same way it is allowed for the close/reopen queues.

<sub>(I'm also curious as to how audits will be implemented in this queue - what will our "positive" and "negative" review options be? If the post is fine, why would it be there in the first place?)</sub>

Comment: If memory serves, the idea is that posts remain in the queue until they get manually kicked out as being sufficiently edited. I.e., *after* somebody has edited them at least once. This might happen immediately after a reviewer hits them, but the OP might get to it first, or some unrelated editor, or the first editor might not be sure it's good enough yet, or ….

Comment: `the people who are answering the questions actually have the ability to make the question better` -- The people who are answering the questions should be spending their time answering questions, not fixing them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why can't they do both?

Comment: They can, but everyone has a busy life, and everyone's time is limited.  Every minute spent fixing questions is one less minute that can be used to actually answer questions.  Our main purpose here is to provide answers, not to be copy editors.

Comment: Interesting. I often have the *exact opposite* experience: I find that often (though certainly not always) the biggest thing *making* me do in-depth edits is because I did not understand entirely what the question was about.

Comment: `However, I've found that the biggest thing that stops me from making in-depth edits is not understanding entirely what the question is about.` Sounds like things that should be left untouched. If you start messing with the core contents of the question, there's a fat chance you'll make radical changes which alters the very meaning of the question.

Comment: @Lundin Right, which is why I think it's important to be able to tag filter the queue.

Comment: Added a bug request to your botscript https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit/issues/45

Comment: @AstroCB Can you please include some instructions in the README.md file, how to install / use this script? Not everyone's a web developer/programmer/whatever.

Comment: @fancyPants I'll add [some instructions](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info); thanks.

Comment: Oh, I'm thanking you. It seems you've done a good job with this script.

Answer (score 22):

I have abandoned edits where I began to fix several simple formatting + spelling + wording issues but then realised that the poor original wording meant I did not understand the question. I then thought that any changes I made to the unclear part of the question were as likely to hide the real question rather than revealing it. This may be what you meant by item 2 (ie *There's not enough information given - you can't really improve it without a missing piece, but you didn't realize it was missing when you started*) in the question.

Comment: I've had this happen quite a few times as well.  I think I know what the individual is trying to say, then I get through the edit and think... "maybe that wasn't what they were trying to say at all..."

Answer (score 20):

I don't usually abandon edits.  I decide ahead of time whether I'm going to edit a post or not.

On a number of occasions, the community has stated that, if you're going to edit a post, then you should fix all of the problems that you find.  When I edit, I generally do so when I see only one, maybe two problems that are easily fixable.  If a post is riddled with problems, I don't edit it; I ask the OP to fix it themselves.  Most of the time, they won't.

I'm of the opinion that the experts are here to answer people's questions, not serve as proofreaders or copy editors.  And no, the answer is not to just embrace bad punctuation and spelling, either.

Comment: Following that reasoning, shouldn't closing and the roomba both have more of a bite?

Comment: "the community has stated that, if you're going to edit a post, then you should fix all of the problems that you find" - This is a true statement (the community does say this), and I agree with the sentiment. However, it seems that the community doesn't practice what it preaches (though those may be two disparate groups). Some recent changes (e.g. removal of "too minor") suggest that *any* improving edit is welcome. But I agree that if fixing an entire post (and it does feel dirty to me not to do so) seems like too Herculean of a task I won't bother.

Comment: I don't think that should become common practise in the triage. You can make small edits, the community helps the OP to fix their question together - incrementally. The post just stays in the review queue until it is acceptable.

Comment: @davidism: Someone else getting an edit in before I'm done.  It's one of the reasons I don't engage in heroic edits anymore, and the main reason why I don't typically abandon edits (because I've decided first whether to edit or not).

Comment: `If a post is riddled with problems, I don't edit it` - I agree with this 99% of the time. There is the rare exception where the problems the post is riddled with are from inexperience with either the interface or the english language but the technical aspects are all there intact.

Comment: I will often retag problematic questions (particularly questions containing code but without a language tag) in the hope an appropriate expert will have enough context to fix the post.  But otherwise, I won't correct grammar/etc. on posts with technical issues.

Comment: The way I see this queue working is, you'll see a pack of people that really _enjoy_ editing, while occasionally asking or answering something working on questions so that they're optimized for those who do come here _specifically_ to answer and only answer. This is a queue for questions that would have been pretty good, had their authors been able to make them that way, often after giving it their best shot. These are questions not likely to be closed, not likely to get many answers, but _very_ likely to stick around - might as well polish 'em and make them better.

Answer (score 18):

One of the things that gets me are people who don't format their code.

**It drives me up the wall to see:**

#include 'std_lib_facilities.h'

int main()
{

//this is supposed to be some comment

cout << 'Hello World!\n';
return 0;

}

**or even worse:**

NSOperationQueue *myqueue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSBlockOperation *downloadOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [cell.actindi startAnimating];
        image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[frontimage objectAtIndex:0]]]];

---

All I want to do is add some spaces or accent marks, but only doing that doesn't always meet the minimum character requirement (I guess whitespace doesn't count?).

At that point I usually:

1. Search for any possible grammatical and/or punctuation errors (makes
   me feel like a cheater changing all of the "it is" to "it's" 20 times just to get those characters in there).
2. Add a comment with a link to the [markdown
   help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) after abandoning the
   edit.
3. Give up, deciding it's not worth my time (this just happened >5 minutes ago).

I'm not saying that there aren't ways around not meeting the minimum requirement, but it is *a* factor which leads me to abandon an edit.

A simple way of just formatting the code without having to meet the requirement would be dandy.

Comment: You can add `<!-- language: lang-js -->` comments ([intended for when the autodetect gets it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) to the top of the code block to meet the requirement.

Comment: Yes @JeffreyBosboom. Yes I could...

Comment: I am fighting the urge to "fix" the formatting your example, even though the _point of the example is that it is bad_.

Answer (score 17):

I'll be honest...

#### I stopped getting rep for editing posts a long time ago.

Sometimes I'll start, realise its not worth it and I know I'm not going to get anything from it. So I remember the sunk cost fallacy, realise its all cost and no reward and quit.

I wouldn't mind a drop from `+2` rep to `+1` rep, but rep is basically a recognition of work, badges a recognition of *alot of work*. Its pavlovian, but I like seeing my rep rise, even if it is by 1.

Comment: Would progress toward additional badges provide any additional incentive for you?

Comment: Honestly, no. I wouldn't mind the rep bump dropping from 2 to 1.

Comment: I've actually become more likely to edit posts since I stopped getting reputation for editing posts. On other sites were I do get rep, the post needs to have much more significant errors that I can correct before I'll bother submitting a suggested edit.

Comment: -1. One should not edit a post to get rep but to improve the post.

Comment: This is the main problem of SO reputation model: that the rep is a mix of moderator skills and technical knowledge. Naively SO assumes that a great moderator must also have great technical knowledge, and vice versa. Which is of course just nonsense.

Comment: @Tim Post: I hope you're not actually going to implement any additional badges. We don't need someone [writing scripts to farm edit badges and potentially messing things up big-time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284919/replaced-with-quot-in-edit) (in that particular case it was not to game anything, but *add* the game factor to that and it gets worse).

Comment: @Jongware And people should not answer questions for rep, but to help the asker. The whole economy of SO is built on rep, otherwise it wouldn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, but let's agree to disagree. I'm here to learn stuff -- and if I can answer a question, I do. If I can help keep the quality of the site high (or not *too* low), I do. If I earn some reputation, and through that, more privileges ... I can use them.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this is relevant to what you're doing, but for completeness: sometimes I will start an edit for a post just in order to copy (or perhaps just look at) some of the markdown.  On these occasions, I never intended to *actually* edit the post, but from the site's point of view I've abandoned the edit.

Comment: I remember looking for a 'view source' link before realizing editing would show me the markdown.

Answer (score 14):

Today I simply wanted to add code highlighting to someones question, but it wasn't possible because I had to edit at least 6 characters.

Comment: After a while this restriction disappears, its just to stop people making insignificant edits for the `+2`.

Comment: Ok, but if this happens one time to me and don't know this, I don't try to make such changes anymore.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr : can you please define *after a while*? Is it a time or a reputation restriction?

Comment: @A.L: that can be found [in the Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: @Jongware I knew that it disappears after 2000+ reputation, but I think *after a while* is ambiguous. It's only true if you earn points, maybe I'm misunderstanding *after a while* (from my understanding of English it's only related to time).

Comment: @A.L: You still need *time* to accumulate 2000 reputation though.

Answer (score 13):

Lack of ability to bulk indent code snippets (i.e. indent multiple lines at a time) within the editor has caused me to not edit code samples with severe indentation issues.

Occasionally I'll be motivated enough to copy it out of the editor, apply the indentation changes quickly in my coding environment and paste it back into the editor, but usually I don't spend the time.

`Update:` Browser extensions / apps to make this easier do exist, as users have pointed out in the comments. I honestly hadn't looked too hard for extensions since SO is the only place I would normally be trying to do editing like this in a browser. I still think making this a built-in feature would still be an improvement.

Comment: See the [SE like I like it userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/5038/24266) browser plugin in order to add and remove tabs in the editor.

Comment: the ItsAllText browser extension is only a Ctrl-Alt-T away from your favourite editor, and updates the textarea in question automagically. I don't leave home without it. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/

Comment: Nice - thanks for the heads-up!  I'll update my answer to reflect the fact that I'd prefer this to be a built-in feature.  :-)

Comment: You can't just select the code and click the 'code block' button (the `{ }` icon)?  That's always worked for me.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're correcting?

Comment: Selecting the code and clicking the 'code block' button works if everything should be flat.  However, sometimes the indentation in the original answer will be random or contains nested logic but isn't indented.  In those cases, I sometimes want to to select multiple lines and do the equivalent of clicking tab two or three times.

Answer (score 10):

I check the OP profile and see he has asked many questions so far and none/few of the previous even dared to mark an answer as accepted.

This makes me think about a person just trying to get a fast answer without really caring about the quality of his contributions, so I prefer to keep the question "ugly" to push the OP to improve his behaviour in the community.

Answer (score 10):

**I abandon edits when I need to refer to the OP's original post to confirm my edit is true to their intent,** but can't because I'm far enough along such that my edit has substantially changed the wording.

This happens when editing posts by non-native English speakers.  I'll extensively correct the grammar, but then need to review the exact phrasing in the OP to confirm I've not altered its meaning.

It would be nice to quickly view the original post without opening another browser window, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The other kind of concurrent edit.

I don't mean the "you may only edit this post if your edit is more substantial" stoppage on submission; I mean having your edit go through and then seeing another one appear quickly after which reverts a bunch of your fixes.

Especially if the new edit is extremely minor or obnoxious (e.g. adding code formatting to random words). Doubly especially if the culprit was a suggested edit which was robo-approved. Triply especially if the new edit adds something important, so you can't just roll it back.

Obviously this won't cause abandonment of an in-progress edit, but when my carefully wrought edit disappears in a resurgence of bad grammar, my will to continue curating that post often goes with it.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to *start* editing when the formatting of the question is so bad that I can't make heads or tails out of it. If, after some basic formatting, code blocks in particular, the question becomes clearer, then I proceed. If, on the other hand, things don't become any clearer, and I'm not even certain that the formatting I introduced was semantically correct, then I give up and abandon the edit, often downvoting and/or voting to close instead.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes I only go into editing mode because I think the question may be garbled due to formatting (newlines ignored because not in a code block, disappearing `>` `<` characters because of code not being in backticks). If I see that the problem is not due to one of these reasons, then I abandon the edit.

Answer (score 8):

> There's not enough information given - you can't really improve it without a missing piece, but you didn't realize it was missing when you started.

I [like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252989/241211) improving posts, just for the sake of doing so.

One way is to improve grammar on posts by non-native English speakers, but I've come across a few cases wherein I can fix *most* of the post, but have parts where

- The author's intent is totally unclear.
- I am concerned that my best interpretation would change an unclear and ambiguous text to something unambiguous but incorrect, usually in a language or technology I don't use.

and I drop the edit. Sometimes I still fix other parts of the post where I can interpret the author's intent. Other times I abandon the whole thing.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Talking about answer edits.</sup>

It's rare, but it happens that I start editing only to discover that what I wanted to add/correct is not entirely correct or applicable to the question when I think about it more closely.

Comment: This suggests you are making edits that change the meaning of the post, and should not be made even if they are "entirely correct".  Leave a comment instead.

Comment: I'm talking about adding "important" information to make the answer better. A comment works, but has not much freedom in expressing yourself. I'm not talking about changing information in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I usually abandon an edit when I find that the question can't be answered after an edit (usually a clean-up).

Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277590/queries-costs-in-databases?noredirect=1#comment44909768_28277590) for example; bad question all-round and contains multiple spelling & grammar errors. If these were to be fixed the question would *still* be bad and because of this there's no point in completing edits like this if the question is likely going to be removed anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Accidentally pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (undo) in [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) (it is close to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (cut)). Usually it does ***two*** undo's instead of the expected one, but I am never quite sure what it does, and thus I usually start over.

Comment: Why not simply *Redo* (Ctrl + Y)?

Comment: Or, if you don't want to remember the keyboard shortcut, the editor has a *Redo* functionality: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ediK.gif

Comment: @Bergi: There have been [reports that Redo is unreliable as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416215/double-revert-when-pressing-ctrlz-after-pasting-pasting-something-is-a-for#comment896660_416215) (and other problems). The loss of confidence in the tool is the main point.

Comment: I found the explanation for the behavior in [an answer to *Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor/203190#203190).

Answer (score 5):

I usually abandon edits when I try to fix a typo, but I can't find anything else of significance to change. Obviously this only happens on sites where I don't have enough rep to save it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I've abandoned a few edits because I realized that the formatting, spelling, grammar and/or tags that I thought needed to be fixed didn't actually need to be fixed. Since starting to edit a post doesn't commit anything, I'm don't feel I need to be all that careful before clicking the edit button on a post.

Answer (score 5):

I've edited a post in the past - including uploading an image linked by OP without sufficient reputation to upload himself - where after submitting changes for review, the OP in the mean time has done an update (changing something largely unrelated to my changes), causing my changes to be lost.

After reincorporating my changes to the OP's updated edit, the same happened again, causing my changes to be lost a second time. At that time, I abandoned the edit.

Answer (score 4):

I'll abandon an edit in cases where I feel like my edit might render the edited post unrecognizable to the OP. This happens most frequently with posts from folks where it appears that English isn't their first language. I can often get the core of what they're asking from the broken English version, but in order to make it more comprehensible to native speakers, I would have to rewrite it to a point where I'm no longer confident that the OP would comprehend/recognize it as the same question. Since I was able to extract the core of the meaning from the broken English, I sometimes err on the side of just leaving it as is, rather than risk undermining the OP's understanding of their own question.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, if someone else edits it before me, I'll stop editting because I cannot see the changes without losing my work.

Two ideas that could be implemented:

1. Allow us to save our progress on our edit, so we can see what someone else changed and include those changes in our edit.
2. Let people manually (I don't think automaticly doing this will work) combine recent edits by two separate people by reading the edit summary and figuring out what's the best from both of them. The action of combining two edits would be considered approving both edits by default unless the reviewer specifies otherwise.

Comment: I'd go for git-style merging for edit conflicts!

Answer (score 2):

My reasons for abandoning an edit are one of three, ranked by order of commonness:

1. I realize my edit won't provide much/enough value to publish
2. Somebody edits out from under me
3. I see a squirrel and forget to finish (IE I get sidetracked by other business)

Answer (score 1):

When I give up fighting the awful UX of my tablet computer. They are not designed for typing.

Comment: It doesn't really sound like a problem that SO can solve, does it?

Comment: Not easily, no. In theory a change to the SO UI could reduce the number of edits I abandon.

Comment: Or... just don't buy the hype of tablet computers. Turns out they are quite poorly adapted to the real world, outside the market hype.

Comment: +1 Selecting a large block of unformatted code on an Ipad and trying to format it as code is nearly impossible when it involves much scrolling. Similarly if the code is near the top the various popups for selected text actions end up obscuring the toolbar buttons.

Comment: @Lundin where do you get the idea that the question is only asking for things that SO can solve? The question asks "what causes you to abandon an edit" and this is one cause. It's hardly insoluble anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith I got that idea from common sense. Or are we doing some form of statistic research of reasons why people suddenly cease using their computers, which includes everything from nature calls to power outages?

Comment: @Lundin Reason number one given in the question is "Turns out, you just don't have enough time.". Clearly the focus of the question is research.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's usually a lack of confidence in my interpretation of the question (or answer).

I have no problem making spelling, grammar and formatting corrections and rarely abandon those, but when it comes to fixing a question that is so broken that I'm almost guessing what the OP wanted, I tend to drop it because I can't make enough sense of it to be confident that my cleaned up version is still asking the same question.

The trouble is that these questions will be deleted or closed without a serious edit, and it would not be surprising to me in the least if people rarely bothered editing such posts for the same reason. I usually spot them and say "what's that lassy? there's a poor quality question on SO that will be deleted without a serious overhaul!? sounds like a job for JAMMYPEACH!" but promptly lose enthusiasm when I realise that the reason it's in such poor shape is that nobody else could edit it either. And there are many better editors on SO.

I suppose this would come under #2.

Answer (score 0):

Would start, then do a quick check with the existing answers to make sure it doesn't contradict any of them.

On seeing any user with higher rep, and noting if none of them edited the question at least for the glaring issues, why continue?

If they can't be bothered to fix up a question they're answering because they're spraying their answers everywhere as fast as they can, what's the use?

Downvote the question and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I would say when I edit that I will abandon as a result of number 2 and sometimes, but rarely, number 4.

*Quick edits (format, spelling, grammar)*

The majority of edits I make are to fix formatting, spelling, and grammar. The errors are often small shortcomings which often do not immediately make a post low quality but where I feel I can improve the overall quality of the post with a quick edit. I will abandon these if someone else formats the entire thing first. In this case, there is a race condition present where an entire set of users are performing the same task (and I wish there was a way to prevent n-1 of the n users from working on it at that point; or if there were a way to merge all n edits together).

*Edits which enhance meaning but include jargon*

Following the quick edits as noted above, I will at times dive head first into fixing a post that I have interpreted as being a rational problem with a clear reproduction or identification of the issue. In these cases, I think I mostly get it right.

But speaking to when I abandon these edits, the primary reason which occurs is that part way through I realize I am potentially going to take the post out of context from the author. It isn't that I am changing it on purpose but it is because I am changing it from what they thought it was to more accurately describe what is happening from a technical point of view for future users.

At this point, often I worry that they did not want it to be that technical, will not understand why I changed it to be so technical, or that since they may not understand that it will just get rolled back. Sometimes I will even go so far as to raise the issue on meta or in chat to make sure that my edit is not going to change the intent of the question.

*Edits which reveal multiple questions*

Another situation I have found myself in is the realization that the question must be closed. I usually see these early, but every once in a while, I will edit a post into good form only to realize two questions were asked. One of them is horribly off topic, but the original question had a shot at being on topic. At this point, I am not sure what to do, usually stop editing, and will vote to close it based on its original state with regards to the off-topic portion.

Answer (score 0):

My reasons are:

1. The post has very poor writing that I don't want to fix
2. Someone comments me while I try to edit