# Why Do I Have To Click 'Add A Comment'?

Tags: discussion, comments

Why isn't the comment field just there by default, and why do I need to click the 'add a comment' link to get it to appear? I don't see the need for the extra step.

Are we afraid we'd be encouraging comments by having it default to being visible, or is the possibility of encouraging unnecessary comments the reason for it being hidden behind a link? Just wondering.

Comment: It *is* a big field and lots of bells and whistles. Plus then you'd have to show it for every answer as well. Seems like a huge waste of screen real estate. I like it fine the way it is.

Comment: If you enable keyboard shortcuts from your "preferences" page, you can press `c` to show and focus the comment field.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Why would you "have" to show it for every answer?

Answer (score 15):

From a distance, it makes some sense to make the box visible. But then you have to imagine looking at questions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285064/what-causes-you-to-abandon-an-edit?cb=1), or any other one with tons and tons of answers.

Each textbox is pretty big, without me resizing it...

[image]
and having them between every post
[image]
would be super
[image]
super
[image]
annoying.

I prefer the way it is right now. I don't see any real reason to make them always be open automatically.

Comment: I don't want every comment box open, just the one under the question.

Comment: Why that one? There are as many comments on the answers as there are on the question.

Comment: It's one click to open the comment box and the text box is automatically given focus. That's the same as if the comment box was already open **and** it wastes space.