# Grammatical and stylistical fixes in suggested edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Currently there are a lot of questions about edits and almost all of them remind about grammatical and stylistical fixes. It is said that they need to be made and if they aren't it is interpreted negatively.

But does everyone understand that for most people here English is not their native language?

I'm not sure I can be good at fixing this kind of issues, so why should I? Isn't it better to leave original mistakes instead of adding one's own? Why are users pushed to include such fixes in their edits?

---

Question [Is suggesting an edit to correct grammar considered appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318379/4928642) is not about the same thing. That questions askes about editing grammar, but this one is about treating edits leaving grammar unchanged as incomplete.

Comment: If you do not have a good grasp of the language, why edit in the first place? Apart from simple tag edits, what kind of edits would you be able to perform if you do not trust your English skills?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There are a few cases. Often new users include HTML that is not in `code markdown`, and it becomes invisible in their post. Just fixing this can save the post.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, true. I would treat that kind of salvaging the same way as tag edits -- get the job done, leave grammatical and stylistic issues to another editor if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix as much as you can, but not more.

If you're not sure about the grammar, leave it alone. You may want to point out, in the Edit Summary, that you left a few things alone because you weren't certain about them.

There are a few things you can almost always do. Fixing "u" and "i" to "you" and "I" is almost always the right choice.

You could also ask someone more experienced in English to help you.

If you find English very difficult, remember the we also have Stack Overflow in a few other languages.