# Why are grammatical edits rejected on SO?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I liked the answer. It solved the my purpose, but it was poorly written and I had to spend some time understanding it.

I tried to improve grammatical quality of that answer, but the edit was rejected. Why is fixing grammatical errors frowned upon?

[Edit Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12277540).

I have seen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318379/is-suggesting-an-edit-to-correct-grammar-considered-appropriate), but wasn't this edit substantial?

Comment: It was a case in which two voters liked your edit and three voters didn't like your edit, with a tiebreaker going towards rejection.  It's a bummer since I don't feel like it should've been rejected...

Comment: I was one of those who rejected the edit. The rejection reason of all three reviewers who rejected was the same;  no substantial *improvement*. IMO the grammar of the original answer is acceptable - there's nothing really  wrong with it and it's perfectly understandable, although it could perhaps be considered somewhat colloquial.

Comment: @CindyMeister what the... why would you reject an edit that changes i for I´s? Just that would have earned an approve from me.

Comment: That's not all that was changed, though, was it? As far as I'm concerned, most of the changes were a matter of personal taste - for me, that puts it in the same category as code indenting. Everyone has their opinion, which is why there's Reviewing by the Community, not by individuals. We don't always agree with how the Community decides... When I on occasion look at how Reviews in which I'm involved turn out I often scratch my head at the decision <shrug> But all you can do is accept it and move on.

Comment: @CindyMeister you have a "Reject and edit" button for that.... use it!

Comment: @CindyMeister: I see your point. On occasion I also rewrite sentences, but I try to limit myself to correcting exceedingly bad grammar  only. The original wasn't that bad, apart from the eyes (which, guest420420, would have been such a minor change for someone with your reputation that it also would warrant a plain "too minor").

Comment: I'm not sure if I would have approved that edit.  There are only a couple real improvements.  Mostly, it is just rewording.  The old wording seems fine to me, so I would say, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".  The OP had his own way of wording things, and pointless changes to it are harmful.  Since you had a couple real improvements, however, I would rate your edit as completely neutral.

Comment: This edit just replaces some words with others. There is no improvement whatsoever, only a matter of personal preference - it doesn't help understand the content, the quality is not improved. I would also have rejected this edit.

Comment: I do not somehow agree with the view that "grammatical" edits do not improve question/answer quality. It does, in my opinion, but thanks for the explanations everyone :)