# How to treat bad English sentence syntax and typo hell?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I have recently come across questions with messed up English sentence syntax ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37100247/1) - subsequently edited). While the English is generally OK (as far as I can tell), there are many typos and, what's worse, spaces before instead of after punctuation or none at all, and no capitalization at the start of sentences.

It is hard to believe that the OP does not know how to use punctuation and spacing correctly, so they either think it's a cool style or are just completely lazy, which I consider as disrespect to the rest of the people visiting SO.

What is a good way to tell them friendly but strongly to please get the most basic sentence formatting fixed? I would not want to downvote on such a formality.

Should I just edit and fix the question, hoping they see the difference? What is a good short comment, possibly with a link?

Comment: One word: Edit ....

Comment: Some users aren't native English speakers so they don't understand English punctuation and grammar rules very well. Others went to elementary, middle, and high school in the U.S. so they...don't understand English punctuation and grammar rules very well. ;)

Comment: Punctuation is a little like the application of white space in code. Sure you could technically write an entire class without a single new line, but ... few people would easily understand the code if you did ;)

Comment: If the Q is good enough to be worth saving, save it by editing properly. If not, well, downvote and move on.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Punctuation is ___trivial___ to understand. It doesn't require any significant intelligence to understand the positioning of punctuation. If a user is capable of writing English words, he has the mental capability not to put spaces before punctuation.

Comment: @Cerbrus: 95% agree. With regard to spaces before punctuation specifically: That's the norm in some languages, such as French where there's a space before `!` or `?`, so that specific issue could easily be just habit from the native language. But in general, when I see these things with the word "I" not capitalized (you don't get through the first ESL lesson without learning it is), using txtspk, etc., I despair a bit. :-)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: As someone who is not a native speaker of English, I think you're being very condescending to everyone who *does* make an effort.

Comment: @Joren: I completely agree. _"Some users aren't native English speakers so they don't understand English punctuation and grammar rules very well."_ is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Joren I am not a native English speaker, either, so I have every excuse to write bad posts. But I don't let that get in the way. It's a different thing that I found English easy from the very beginning.

Comment: @Cerbrus: as it is, that sentence contains false implication (a=>b, a="not native", b="not understand grammar"). I wanted to throw in a joke that we can fix this easily by flipping it around (a<=b).. but then it occurred to me that it actually wouldn't be true either!

Comment: I have the same problem like you. I get annoyed. Edit and train them is the only solution. You cannot deal with general chaos of the world, most people are pretty chaotic and hence they don't pick up programming like others I feel.  And as programmers we have OCD towards perfection. Both are like contradictory but a fact of life. I have noticed that good programmers are excellent at punctuation because they are already doing seperation of concern when they write. When you become more serious you pick up this because you realize you can't study from chaos. No offence but an obeservation :)

Comment: The punktuation I do understand, but grammar is an entirely different beast to learn - especially the finer points. I never understood grammar very well - even after learning english for years. Am I lazy by default because of this "fault" of mine?

Comment: @Rhayene: There's a difference between making a few mistakes in a post, and just throwing all rules out of the window, as the OP of the linked question did.

Comment: [Space before punctuation is not their fault](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645) (by "their" I mean statistically speaking). Unlearning is not easy.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: A programmer is capable of getting used to adding semicolons where required. Spacing for punctuation is no different.Even so, those that add spaces before punctuation usually mess up more than just that.

Comment: Oh, [the irony](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32456/correct-usage-for-bad-v-poor-adjectives#comment58419_32464). ;^)

Comment: I think the post is not that bad. Some people really just never practice typing correctly. It may have started out when they first learn typing/writing, when they dismissed the rules as "not important", not realizing that it will be helpful later, and that habit carries out until now. Also, read about [Dunning-Kruger Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) that might be applied when one first learns something, with unfortunately noone to correct them, or that they dismissed them as being authoritative.
But again, this isn't an excuse. Just that it isn't typo hell.

Comment: @justhalf: Just because someone never learned it, doesn't make it "OK". There is _no_ excuse for such an lack of effort.

Comment: Yap, indeed, it shows a lack of effort and I agree that it is not ok. My comment was explaining why it could happen (and also add my personal opinion that it is still readable and understandable, and so not something I would call "typo hell"). =D

Comment: *"It is hard to believe that the OP does not know how to use punctuation and spacing correctly"* - Judging by the username, English is not OP's mother tongue. Probably a fresher out of college who is only used to typing English in texts, chat messages etc.

Comment: @Cerbrus first of all they should know that there is a "lack of effort" from their part and their post needs improvement. They probably don't know that and believes it's fine until you tell them otherwise.

Comment: @TJ: _"English is not OP's mother tongue"_ is _not_ an excuse. (See my answer here).

Comment: @Cerbrus Nobody is making any excuse. OP probably doesn't know there is such thing as punctuation and it's important in forums like this. Do we  show them an alert saying that "There is such thing called punctuation and it's important, you can learn it from here (link)" when they are about to post their first question? I don't think so. Not knowing something is not a fault, or mistake. It can be considered as lazyness/bad behavior of OP only if they are doing so after they have been informed about such things.  See my comment to your answer.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: I would say that very often it is more likely to say `b => not a` Language learners often learn more of the grammar as rules in the new language than native speakers do. This is because the native speakers just "know" what it should be like without necessarily knowing the rules behind it.

Comment: @TJ to be honest, as a non native speaker, I have recently started just downvoting (and sometimes voting to close) very badly formatted questions or questions that have a clear lack of any sort of proofreading.

Comment: I found funny the edits on your question (not that I could do it better either, as a non-native English speaker)

Comment: @Cerbrus "(...) Spacing for punctuation is no different.Even so (...)" -- Think you missed a space there.

Comment: I'm only human, @Daniel ;-)

Comment: @justhalf; there is no word "noone". There are two words, "no one". Sorry if I come across as being authoritative ;).

Comment: I tried too, but the edit got rejected :P http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322655/why-are-grammatical-edits-rejected-on-so

Comment: I think my c++ compiler enforces all the syntax check I need. I don't fancy yet another syntax checker to catch my spelling mitsakes.

Answer (score 145):

I would say that yes, correct the post, but also offer a polite comment, so that their future posts might be better. I sometimes say something like this for Java-related questions:

> Programming is an exercise in precision since the Java compiler and JVM are strict and non-forgiving, so when asking a programming question, you will want your communication to be as clear as possible to avoid any chance for ambiguity. Also, for many here, English is not their first language, and it may be hard for them to understand posts, especially if they contain obscure and non-standard abbreviations. I'd say more than half the comments on this site are requests for clarification. Let's avoid these.

Comment: This is very good.  I seldom remember to say the first five words; how can you expect to be a good programmer if you can't get the English language right?

Comment: I would leave out the part about 'Java' compiler 'and JVM'. All computers are 'strict and non-forgiving', and so are nearly all programming languages. Programming is a discipline.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you don't even need to know English to become a good programmer, just need to learn some tokens, which even native English speaker need to learn. Even though most of those tokens look like English they are different.

Comment: @bansi Given that all good literature and documentation are written in English, it actually turns out that you _do_ need to know English in order to become a half-decent programmer.

Comment: @Lundin, you don't have to read documentation to be a good programmer. BTW, there are translations of literature to different languages as well as blogs on other languages. So, no you don't need to know English in order to be a good programmer.

Comment: Indeed, most great literature is to be found in all languages, and English is not required to be a great programmer.

Comment: But English _is_ required to be a functioning contributor on SO.

Comment: @ixSci "You don't have to read documentation to be a good programmer." Oh, dear. This may be the most false sentence I've ever seen on SO.

Comment: Given that the english language is the most popular language,it's crucial that the programmar be articulate to be able to express himself and interact with the programming environment.

Comment: @machine_1: re `"Given that the english language is the most popular language..."` -- World wide [English is number 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers). The number 1 language, Mandarin Chinese beats English almost 3 to 1.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Native speakers is different from speakers ;) - in which case English does win out.

Comment: @ixSci Sorry, I wish it wasn't so, but it is. Once you start working as a professional programmer you'll realize a big part of your job is to read lots of technical documentation. Programming books, tutorials, API documentation, formal standards, coding standards, tool documents, in-house documentation...

Comment: @Lundin, I have 10 years experience working as a professional programmer. And what I have seen during these years is that many libraries have either no documentation at all or have so little that you can't extract anything valuable from it. In fact I can name just a few frameworks with good documentation. Qt is one of those but I can't count times I had to dig into the source code to truly understand how and why it behaves like it behaves. So even if you can't read the documentation you can always read code, reverse-engineer a thing etc. In most cases it is harder but it might give you more

Comment: @Lundin, what I'm trying to say is that it is not impossible to learn without documentation. Most of the time it will be harder but it is not impossible.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Terrible excuse. If one's capable of adding semicolons where necessary, that person has the capability to add punctuation and capitalization where necessary.

Comment: English may not be the most popular language, conceding the title to Mandarin Chinese, but it surely is the most influential language in the field of computer programming, where Mandarin Chinese is simply irrelevant. While some important works do get translated to other languages, many more don't, and the translations are often outright horrible. A non-native English speaker myself, I consider English the most important technical skill, probably more important than programming itself - you may be using C++ today and Java a year later, but you will be reading English documentation in both cases

Comment: @Headcrab: As someone who speaks both English *and* Mandarin Chinese (OK maybe not bilingual...), I can confirm I've never read, spoken or written a single word of Chinese in any computer programming context, be it documentation, or everyday conversation with other programmers (even ones from China - and I know a quite handful of them, and they've all proactively spoken English).

Comment: Devil's advocate: Remember that up until perhaps 70 years ago German was the language of technology and science and before that Latin, and I expect that the "default" language of technology will continue to evolve and shift.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Straw man. ~70 years ago we were at war with Germany. What possible reason could there be for the "default" language of technology to shift? Even languages that outnumber English, are using English for technology.

Comment: Try editing the post so that user can also improve his/her English

Comment: It would be helpful for new users as well

Comment: @Cerbrus: German lost its status as language of technology and science not because of the war, but because of many of its former speakers in science left Germany to the shores of the United States.
That being said: I would say, that the most popular _intercultural_ language is English in any of its varieties. Therefore, anyone dealing with SO should show some effort in also _writing_ this language.

Answer (score 114):

I am seeing quite a few comments excusing an extreme lack of punctuation or grammar with something like:

> *"English isn't the primary language of that user."*

English is a secondary language *for me*. I have no problem applying proper punctuation. *Anyone* that is capable of learning a second language sufficiently to be able to read and write in it, has the mental capability to capitalize "I", and to properly add punctuation.

However, there's a massive difference between having a *couple* of mistakes in one's Q/A, and just throwing *all* rules out of the window, as shown in the example linked by the OP.

Lacking punctuation is more often than not accompanied by the complete absence of capitalization, txtspk, and other lazy things like that.
*"It's a second language"* is a poor excuse. If you're capable of writing English words, you're capable of putting some effort into punctuation.

There are a bunch of guides on asking, and users are expected to post **clear, grammatically correct questions / answers**. Sure, a mistake can happen, but show us you've put *some* effort into the post.

Stack Overflow is an English exclusive site. There are different (Stack Exchange) sites for other languages.

---

That all said, the best you can do is to **edit the post if it's salvageable**.

Comment: You're grasp of English, and the nuances of its punctuation, is exquisite, but many people learn English only (or primarily) orally, so I think it's wrong to assume that others would share your formidable command of this language.

Comment: @Strawberry: _"Your / it's"*_. It's impossible to learn a language orally. You wouldn't know how to write the words, not to mention compose a coherent question.

Comment: So how does my dictation software work?

Comment: @Strawberry: It has been taught through the programming work of a software developer, not by listening to one.

Comment: Also I believe you meant "aurally".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No. I meant "orally", but that works too. I did however mean "Your", and not "You're" ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry: Well you _definitely_ can't learn English orally. Although maybe one day we'll finally have learning pills!

Comment: Oral refers to speaking in this context. I seem to remember I learnt English that way.

Comment: @Strawberry: How can you learn English by _speaking_? How would you know what to say?

Comment: @Strawberry you mean you learned by listening, yes?  I think you two are just getting into the semantics of what exactly "oral" means, and probably "aural" and "oral" both work for what you mean.  First definition is "by word of mouth" and/or "spoken rather than written."  I think hearing is implicitly implied in the definition.

Comment: Seriously, I know what I meant, thanks. I meant to use the word oral. Others may have preferred I use another word, but I suspect that's because they don't properly comprehend the meaning of the word oral.

Comment: You all are assuming OP intentionally posts with improper punctuation. Some people just don't know that punctuation is important, or even such thing exists. Major population of the world comes from  non-English speaking countries. I am from one of them and I don't remember learning proper usage of punctuation in English  at school. I learned "I" should be capital from StackOverflow... if you know what I mean.

Comment: @TJ: Capitalization =/= punctuation. If the OP puts _no_ effort at all in writing a proper post, we don't have to tolerate it. It is _their_ responsibility to write a coherent, properly formatted post. If they don't know any better, they better pay attention when their posts get edited. Once again: Editing a post isn't a punishment. The OP should take it as an opportunity to _learn_.

Comment: @Cerbrus For me, capitalizing "I" is fairly non-intuitive, and i often simply don't remember to do that. It doesn't catch my eye like it does for others - or for me in my first language. Not that I mind other people fixing my typos or punctuation/capitalization/grammar errors.

Comment: I was (and still am) one of the fiercest supporters of the SO sites in other languages, and one of those responsible for the initial momentum of SO in Portuguese. Not only I agree with this, I am all in favor of going full Jules Winnfield on people who make posts that have grammatical issues.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How do people manage to learn syntax rules of programming languages and yet fail to manage syntax rules of English? Quite simple. With little help from parsers and compilers. You cannot feed them anything you want or your code will not compile. If nothing else that is how people learn those. With English all bets are off, especially when it comes to non-native English speakers. I am not justifying them, I am saying that their mistakes might not be obvious to them.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Not really, no. For example, one could just _casually glance_ at this very comment thread and notice that people are beginning their sentences with capital letters, and ending them with full stops. How hard is that?

Comment: @TJ You know Hindi and English share official status in your country, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, none of them are my mother tongue. Did you know that there are 22 official languages in India? and there are more of them...  sadly most of the kids from school or freshers out of collage who usually posts questions like this doesn't know *professional* English usage (*yet*).

Comment: English is not official language in all the countries

Comment: But is _is_ in TJ's ^_^

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, While it is true that C++ is not a first language, C++ (or most computer languages) have very few exceptions.  English is so full of exceptions that "Exceptions are the Rule".  Take the Oxford Comma (https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it), for example.  "Use of the Oxford comma is stylistic, meaning that some style guides demand its use while others don’t."

Answer (score 22):

I agree with Hovercraft - fix the post. However, I disagree about the comment part, polite or not. In most cases, when you're just fixing language and grammar, no real value is served in leaving a comment. If you are unsure that you've accurately reflected the OP's *intent*, then by all means, you should comment and let them know. But a comment that isn't about the meaning of the content is simply noise.

> ...spaces before instead of after punctuation or none at all, and no capitalization at the start of sentences.

Easy fix: **the [Magic™ Editor](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#magic-editor)**. [Tiny Giant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant) and I have forked this project from the [Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/4899/stack-exchange-editor-toolkit), and extended it to cover many common grammatical errors, including the specific ones you mention. One click & done.

Texting-English, such as "sry btw, cuz i m new" gets corrected,too.

With script support, it takes so little effort to improve the small details that you can concentrate on the real meat of posts.

No matter what the reasons behind grammatically incorrect posts are, a large number of users will emulate what they see. By quietly correcting and improving posts, you provide a growing body of good examples. Keep it up!

Comment: Spam spam: Too much promotion of Magic Editor :)

Comment: Using magic like this is dangerous, specially for coding questions, as something that look like bad grammar can actually be code references.

Comment: Is this Editor usable for composing questions/answers in the first place?

Comment: @awe I think what we want is an autocorrect that suggests fixes to words that weren't found in a dictionary or `code` quoting around those words.

Comment: @PSkocik Browser-based spell check does that, with the caveat that English needs to be installed.

Comment: @Rhayene It wasn't designed to do that, but we've enabled it to work in all question & answer edit boxes. So, yes, it can be used to help clean up new posts.

Comment: @awe Some code references do get treated as prose, but most are recognized as code and left alone. You're shown a diff of the changes, so it's easy to find places that should be reverted. (Better yet - backtick code references to start, and they'll be left as-is.)

Comment: Yes, but there is a certain false positive error rate with the *Magic Editor*. I suppose it is not really fire and forget. Perhaps you should mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 22):

I am one of the guys who was responsible for the initia momentum of SO in Portuguese. I fiercely defended the creation of SO in other languages too.

English is not my native language. I know how it feels to come to SO (or any other site, for that matter) which is not in my native tongue.

Now that I have provided my background, I will provide my opinion on what to do with posts that have too many grammatical issues. If an image is worth a thousand words, then an animated one is worth a million.

[image]

Seriously. If you can't speak the common language of a site, you won't solve your problems there. Doesn't matter if it's programming or whatever else.

Answer (score 10):

The way I see it, these questions generally fall under 3 categories, and I respond to them accordingly;

**1. I understand what the poster is trying to ask, and it's a good question:**   I just edit these and then do whatever I would normally do with the question (upvote/comment/answer).

**2. I understand what the poster is trying to ask, and it's a bad question:**  I don't bother editing, and do whatever I would normally do with the question (downvote/flag/vote to close/just walk away).

**3. I don't even understand what the poster is trying to ask:**  I leave this (or something close to it) comment:  "Can you please ask a native English-speaker to help you re-write your question?  It is not at all clear what you are trying to ask."   If I come back to the same question later and nothing has been clarified, I vote to close as "Unclear".

I like to imagine that some of those Cat-3 questions were actually asked by native English-speakers who were just being lazy, and that my comment has a positive influence on their future communication efforts.   : )

Comment: 4. When you somehow understand the question, edit it, answer it, and the OP dosen't even understand your answer... It's the most dramatique case. How did the idea of using stackoverflow ever came to his mind... he can't even read english... (the guy was probably using google traduction... not always the best tool)

Comment: Category 3 should really be downvoted and/or closevoted as unclear.

Comment: @Cerbrus well that's what I do if the poster doesn't edit their question later.

Comment: ["You should wait for zero seconds..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Comment: I downvote immediately, post a comment pointing out the problems with the question and asking the OP to improve, and in the unlikely case where they do, I'll switch my vote to an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how much rep you have. I tried to fix a simple typo once but the system wouldn't let me because the fix was too simple. I asked about it and was told that if you're going to fix something like that you should try to fix other stuff with the question while you're there, because edits by low rep users have to go through a review and simple edits fill up the review queue and waste time. It's better to let a user with a higher rep fix it so it doesn't have to go thru a review.

Comment: If you are fixing _one_ typo it's not worth a edit review, but fixing an entirely terrible incomprehensible post is fine at any reputation level.'

Comment: I think that's what he's saying, @ryanyuyu.

Comment: quite interesting point. if it's just punctuation then we don't bother correcting it when read it. we are humans in the first place so no matter what language we can tolerate those errors. not worth taking time slapping on other people's face saying "hey you don't speak english well so your problem must be bad."

Comment: @Yvon: You're missing the point here. Improving the quality of a post isn't "punishment". If you see someone make a typo, or misplace some punctuation, edit it.

Comment: i'm referring to the voting system. should one down vote a question because bad grammar / punctuation and you don't even want to fix it. downvoting is punishment since grammar not related to question itself.

Comment: We downvote poor quality questions / answers. In my opinion, it's extremely rude to post a question on SO and then expect someone to put effort into answering it, when one hasn't taken any effort to write a coherent, decently formatted question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a go at formatting your question more correctly:

> I have recently come across several questions, in English, which are grammatically incorrect.
>
> While the English itself is generally alright, there are many typographical errors and, worse still, spaces before - instead of after - punctuation, or no spaces at all, and no capitalization at the start of sentences.
>
> It is hard to believe that the OP does not know how to use punctuation and spacing correctly, so either they think this some sort of 'cool style', or they are lazy, which I consider disrespectful to everyone else visiting SO.
>
> What is a good way to tell them, in a firm but friendly manner, to improve their grammar?
>
> I would not want to downvote on such a triviality.
>
> Should I simply edit and fix the question, hoping that they see the difference?
>
> What might be an appropriate, short comment, possibly with a link?

One of the great joys of English and, I suspect, a reason for its proliferation, is its tolerance of precisely such abuses. Long may they continue.

Comment: There's a big difference between various pedantic minor changes that increase readability ever-so-slightly, and trying to salvage something comprehensible that resembles English from a flood of utter crap. We don't expect people to produce state of the art Oxford Dictionary English. We expect them to produce something that a person with basic English knowledge can read and understand.

Comment: @Lundin Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

As a user who is not a native English speaker, I want to say: fix the question and explain the problems in a comment. At least that's what I want when I face with a problem like this. I want to see my grammar mistakes so I can fix them in the future. For example, even in this answer you'll see grammar problems.

Since I can, at least communicate with other people grammar is not a big problem for me, but still I'm trying to be careful.

When people use "a" instead of "an" is really annoying though, even I don't make that mistake.

Comment: I would take out the last sentence. Everyone is different and has their individual problem zones (It took me a long while to learn this "a" "an" rule properly). So saying "even I don't make that mistake" is not quite helpful since it only describes your own handle on english and may be read as rude by people who have indeed problems with this rule.

Answer (score 1):

We really need to find a balance and try to encourage the folks who are non-native English speaker and have bad English sentence syntax and typo. Nobody is perfect. We should not demotivate a programmer to ask good quality questions because he or she has bad English syntax and typo hell.

I understand that sometime it’s really annoying when somebody makes horrible mistakes, like no punctuation, no capitalization at the start of the sentence. Personally, I would edit and try my best to train them. Believe me that those folks will learn from their mistakes and make progress if they ask again. Well, it’s possible to be a good programmer even if you can’t get the English language right because many countries offer an option to study and work full-time in their local languages.

After all, we are not linguistic or news reporters to focus on our English grammar or punctuation. But, we should try our best so that it does not annoy us when we read through the question. After having studied, lived and worked in different countries with many non-native English speakers, I have started to respect the programming abilities of many folks and we should not just judge them depending on their English language competencies.

Let’s be polite and encourage those folks and also teach them not to ask for excuses their whole life.

Comment: A positive point of view, but if someone always is going to correct bad English, without any comment, this means that we actually are teaching OPs that they do not really have to take care of proper grammar.

Answer (score -2):

I came to programming via publishing, where I worked as an editor for many years. I can easily be overweeningly punctilious – not to mention verbose and sesquipedalian – both in my own writing and in my reaction to that of others. I do try to restrain myself. Sometimes.

Those of you who publish in scientific and technical fields will be amused to know that your editor has heard (and probably repeated) the quip “Broken English is the international language of science.”

That having been said, my professional advice is this:

Genuine ambiguities should be queried; mere solecisms should be politely ignored, even if you are the type of person who corrects other people's grammar and pronunciation at parties.

[edit] Well, this has been educational. Apparently, many SO denizens find ornately correct English extremely objectionable. Lesson learnt.

Comment: Punctilious, sesquipedalian, solecisms... We're programmers here. Not majors in English.

Comment: Clarification: I have never _ever_ seen those 3 words before. (English is a secondary language for me. That may be related). It may be correct English, but frankly, it appears kind-of pompous.

Comment: @Cerbrus: a lot of meaning can be inferred from context - well, maybe not. I think "sesquipedalian" means he has 6 legs.

Comment: Sesquipedalian means "of or pertaining to long words" @Rad... Though the post is deliberately obfuscatory the odd word is still possible to search for, and relying solely on context doesn't, necessarily, work. Hexapod means 6-footed and is often used as a synonym for 6-legged.

Comment: maybe these words are terms of their field (editing)? I mean the term "debugging" does not make sence outside of programming/IT too.

Comment: "People tell me I've got a way with words. They say I'm sequipedelian." "Well, you won't get away with words like that around here." -- _Dave Trampier_

Answer (score -5):

I came here from Matlab tag with a related link. I'm not a native English speaker. For most of the time it's not the broken language that prevents me from understanding OP's problem. It's the broken logic. If someone shows everything needed, such as current code that is giving error (error text attached), expected results, and the data, they even don't have to write any English.

Punctuation followed by a space is not everywhere around the world. So i don't expect everybody at SO type in "the correct way", which seems "correct" to native English speakers. So is capitalizing `I`. (hey whats the difference ?getting insulted by not writing nicelly?)

Try to understand the following problem. Since posts may be edited from time to time, OP's contents are pasted below with no intention of violating copyrights.

example 1 https://stackoverflow.com/q/37099531/3839249

> Any pointers on how to proceed? I am stuck in the summation part.
>
> A_k(z)p^k For k = 0 to M

This question has been put on hold as too broad. How did s/he "get stuck"? If that's a coding problem then please show code. If it's maths then `matlab` is not a proper tag.

example 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100154/matlab-noise-removal

> Could anyone help me with noise removal of my images,
>
> (noisy, colorful images given, with no description at all)

again, very polite English but we simply don't understand what the OP wants to do.

example 3 [Choose elements from array randomly in matlab and store the remain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105881/choose-elements-from-array-randomly-in-matlab-and-store-the-remain-element)

(4 lines of English words with only one comma, followed by example code, with question clearly pointed out, and received working answers)

example 4 [How can I display a 2D binary matrix as a black & white plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280705/how-to-convert-2d-binary-matrix-to-black-white-plot)

(clearly not native English.but no problem with getting answers and respects by others over the years)

Personally I don't take broken language itself as being lazy or disrespectful. Many people come to SO as foreigners in hope that problems can get solved, and they show enough respect to the community. Others may think this is a friendly and cozy site so no need of proof writing. People who answer questions are working in a professional manner meaning that they don't care much about language itself; only need to catch ideas and solve problems. So what's wrong with broken English? Frankly many are treating this community like [customer service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101696/convert-c-to-matlab) but i don't think it is likely that those people who don't speak/write well at here are generally more disrespectful. don't judge other's by there punctuations.

Comment: I agree. Lot of people here are not native English speaker. Also I have also seen some who don't even know English (using translator to post/understand). I would recommend edit the post with a polite comment. About punctuation, in my native language there is almost no space and stops (multiple words and even sentences are valid without a space!)

Comment: Lacking punctuation is more often than not accompanied by the complete absence of capitalization, txtspk, and other lazy things like that. There are a bunch of [guides on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and users are expected to post clear, grammatically correct questions / answers. Sure, a mistake can happen, but show us you've put some effort into the post.

Comment: if that's the case then people should never need to develop proofing software

Comment: Proofing software checks more than just punctuation.

Comment: `users are expected to post clear, grammatically correct questions` this is too strict

Comment: Why is that too strict? Why can't we expect users to put some effort into their questions. By the way, please don't use `code blocks` to highlight _"quotes"_.

Comment: broken language doesn't mean lack of effort. it's other aspects that define how bad a question is but, as far as i know, people who don't speak well  can think carefully.

Comment: The rules of English don't just 'seem' correct to a native English speaker. They are, by definition, correct. Like any language, English has rules. Just as you can't mix Visual Basic 6 syntax into your C program and expect it to be considered correct, neither can you mix the syntax rules of one spoken language into another and expect it to be considered correct.

Comment: "OP's contents are pasted below with no intention of violating copyrights" All postings on SE sites [are licensed to be reusable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). Besides which, saying "I don't intend to do X" isn't any sort of a legal defense if you then deliberately actually do X.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that the problem with the post the OP is asking about is **not** "broken English."  Even poor grammar due to a poster's unfamiliarity with the language (which is just fine! We'll happily edit it up nicely) can be properly punctuated - in this case the poster did not capitalize or punctuate or space *anything* (these are some of the first things you learn) indicating laziness, not poor English.  Therefore your answer is not really applicable.

Comment: Written language is a form of communication. By writing correctly, you can ensure that most people will understand. This is similar to good code standards. Correct code can be both easily readable and completely unreadable. We all prefer the readable variant. Let's apply the same for English communication.

Answer (score -5):

I've carefully reviewed your example. Well it's not the best English I must admit. However there are interesting things to observe from the edit history:

- *mutliple -> multiple:*  Ironically the editor also made a typo *"correcting"* the word to "mutiple". Well, as it seems everyone makes typos, even those of us, who's solely purpose to correct the text, and not focusing on solving a programming problem.

**Answer**

- edit
- and more importantly: patience, understanding, tolerance, not
  thinking in- and using overstatements.
- and most importantly: keeping in mind SO is primarily not
  for lecturing others, instead to helping each other. Improving the quality of a question or answer of course always a good thing.

**One last thought:**

Could you please review the edits made on your question, especially the typos and grammar errors what were corrected by others?

Comment: So, how does this answer the question? Also, did you really look at the [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12283834) of the linked question? There's so much more that was edited.

Comment: @Cerbrus, this answers directly to the question under the title "Answer".

Comment: About review the example, you are right, I missed the very original. Now I corrected my answer.

Answer (score -9):

Just edit the post and correct it.

Comment: You could've upvoted one of the existing answers. This answer doesn't really add to the discussion.

Answer (score -11):

I'm not a native English speaker myself but i think it's perfectly fine to ask a question that's not been asked before, even if the English is a little broken. Afterall, SO is not an English exclusive site, i would be against downvoting it just because the OP wasn't good at English as long as you can understand what they meant to ask, and you can always edit it (probably with annotations) so long as you're sure you would improve the readability of the question. Well, unless OP is clearly lazy.

Edit: Sorry i expressed my point incorrectly, what i meant is that SO is not an exclusive site for only native English speakers, of course you have to write in English to be taken seriously here.

Comment: SO ___is___ an English exclusive site. There are different (stack exchange) sites for other languages.

Comment: I agree with you. My answer was mainly geared towards lazy native English speakers who use non-standard abbreviations in their posts. For non-native speakers, all anyone can ask is that you post as well as as you can.

Comment: @Cerbrus SO is a professional site written in english. people come here to solve practical problems other than teaching the language. can't see the point of votes for your repelling comment.

Comment: The site's language is English. If a user wants to be taken seriously here, he has to write in English. That _includes_ punctuation and grammar.