# Rejection of edit to question raises questions about editing questions

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20790646) was rejected with boilerplate text implying that it made the situation worse.

Needless to say, I felt that the edit clarified the original text, which left me wondering.

1. Are questions supposed to be devoid of punctuation, capitalization, or other syntax?
2. Are there guidelines somewhere that clarify all of this?
3. If so, why was I unable to find them after a good-faith effort to do so?

Comment: Your suggested edit was rejected because two of the reviewers are clueless. There's nothing wrong with the edit.

Comment: @Stijn thanks for the feedback. I'm actually less interested in that particular edit, though, and more in the meta question. Are there guidelines set out somewhere, that I haven't yet found, defining the goals of proposed edits to other peoples' questions?

Comment: Oh, yes there are guidelines. I'll propose a duplicate.

Comment: Re: _"why was I unable to find them after a good-faith effort to do so"_: would you mind going into a little bit more detail as to where you looked and what you were looking for that you didn't find?

Comment: For instance, did you find [the "Editing" article in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)? Or the [Advanced editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (accessible from the ? in the right corner of the editor toolbar)

Comment: @TinyGiant I was looking around on the page linked in the OP. I'm afraid i didn't see either of those links. In the first case, I wasn't aware of the Help Center; in the second, I just didn't think that such information would be under "Advanced". Thanks for the links!

Comment: So, your "good-faith effort" was to look around one page _after you got an edit rejected_? You didn't even know about the help center after three months of activity? You have the [informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=9829403) badge which means you "read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page" on or around May 29 at 18:01 UTC. At the end of the tour page, directly following the "See new questions" and "Ask a question" buttons, is a "Visit the help center" button. There is a "?" icon with a help menu on every page of the site.

Comment: Sorry, but I think we have very different definitions of "good-faith effort".

Comment: I didn't just look at that page. In any event, my failure to read the pages you linked to is kind of academic, considering that neither of them contains information that would have helped me. The fact is that I still don't have an answer to my first question.

Comment: I suppose _[Is suggesting an edit to correct grammar considered appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318379/4639281)_ could be added to the duplicate list for your first question. (if a gold badge holder wanted to do that). I was focusing on the third question because I thought that might have some promise, but the fact that your definition of "good-faith effort" is "as little effort as possible" put a kibosh on that.

Comment: @Tim, your edit was good, but the edit description was a bit poor, in my opinion. Try to be more descriptive of your edits in the edit comment, it makes it more likely your edits will be approved when they deserve to be.

Answer (score 4):

The specific reason was this:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Yours is the sort of edit that should really have a more specific edit reason to specify that this is how it's supposed to look. Ideally, reviewers should skip edits like this if they don't know whether the change improves technical accuracy, but Suggested Edits has more roboreviewers than any other queue.

Need some guidelines? My [best post network-wide](/questions/338662/should-i-stop-editing/338670#338670) should do. As for your third question, perhaps I should try to improve the searchability of such a good canonical; for example, the question title is "should I stop editing", which probably won't grab your attention as what you're looking for.

Comment: s/roboreviewers/keyboard smashing monkeys/ FTFY