# Should editors be leaving errors?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've been doing a bunch of editing, and I'll often find posts that have been edited, usually by a 2k+ user, that are still riddled by mistakes. I have to wonder what was changed, because the entire post is just wrong. It's not "borderline" mistakes anyway; it's usually HUGE grammatical problems like `ive` or `it have`.

I understand that there's no review queue to verify these edits, so editors can do whatever they want (although I assume there's some abuse prevention measures in place). But why would someone edit a post if they were going to leave it a mess?

Should we be discouraging this type of editing? On new questions, where multiple people may begin editing simultaneously, [slower, more thorough editors will likely abandon their work if another edit comes in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285067/6083675).

Personally, I've found that I avoid making edits to new posts for this reason.

Should <2k editors be leaving mistakes? What about 2k+ editors? And what should be done about this, if anything? (Note that I'm not referring to ritualistic burnination edits, which should always fix other errors. I'm asking about edits in general because I just want to know.)

Comment: If a post is unsalvageable, no one should waste any time editing grammar, spelling, etc. It's not uncommon to just fix tags and vote to close.

Comment: I typically edit to improve formatting, not content or grammar.

Comment: @PetahChristian Why fix the tags if it's going to be closed?

Comment: Even a closed question shouldn't be mistagged. It wastes time when it shows up in a feed that has nothing specific to do with that question.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally no, editors should not be leaving mistakes. In reality it happens all the time as you note.

Sometimes editors set out to specifically address an issue that is widespread, and in those efforts they will often leave posts in whatever condition they were already in with the specific issue fixed.

While this may leave mistakes, it is common and at least there was some sort of positive movement on the post in those scenarios. Overall, editing is a very hard tool to use, there are not many incentives for using it, and it has a rather light footprint.

I am not sure there is much that can be done unless the edit was seriously egregious aside from trying to give the guidance of "fix what you can, not just what you saw" when editing. If an edit or editor is actively causing problems, flagging a post with a custom moderator message is a good way to bring attention to it. Moderators do have the ability to lock the editing privilege when warranted.

Answer (score 2):

If a post is worth editing, then it's beneficial to correct everything at once -- readability, formatting, spelling, grammar, as well as tags.

Other posts need to be flagged or closed as soon as possible, and editing the post slows down the time it takes to review or moderate posts. You vote, flag, and/or close, then move on to another question.

Sometimes all you really want to do is correct the tag, but not try to salvage the post. I often come across 2k+ tag edits, without the post body itself being edited. This is useful as questions are often mis-tagged.

- 10k users can edit tags inline, as part of the [moderator tools privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).
- 2k users have to actually edit the post if any tags need to be edited.

Comment: If a 10k+ users edits tags inline, is their name marked as editor?

Comment: Yes. It appears the same as a 2k user who had to use the editor.