# Are GrammarBots supported?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I enjoy answering and nurturing the [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and [rubyonrails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubyonrails) questions on Stack Exchange. However I'm often having to edit the English of a question before addressing the technical bits. Say I wrote a bot to add basic grammar and punctuation suggestion edits. What's the official stance on this type of solution?

Comment: I'm interested about responses as well, mostly because I once considered building a bot like that but refrained.

Comment: Glad to hear the support for a response.

Comment: I'm sure they exist in some capacity; there are unofficial copy editing plugins out there which already do this to some extent.

Comment: The [Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) userscript tries to fix some common errors.

Comment: I'm wary about bots making fully-automated edits, even suggested ones.  At a minimum there needs to be an emergency shutoff somewhere that the bot checks before each edit, as with Wikipedia bots.  If the bot edits slowly enough for someone to notice before it's made all the edits, it will at least limit the damage in [cases like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284919/replaced-with-quot-in-edit).

Comment: I don't think unmonitored bots would be tolerated, but could be wrong. I don't know of any specific precedent or policy. To my surprise this doesn't seem to be explicitly forbidden by the [TOS](http://s.tk/legal/terms-of-service) or [API TOS](http://s.tk/legal/api-terms-of-use). The Stack Exchange [content policy](http://s.tk/legal/content-policy) has a "Mass Registration and Automation" heading, but it doesn't *clearly* forbid this. If the bot were only suggesting changes to you, and you reviewed them and apply other necessary changes before submitting them, that should be fine.

Comment: You might want to be interested in [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically) about an automatic comment flag bot.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom that was the first thing that popped into my mind when I saw this point.  I think that deserves to be in an answer as a warning

Comment: @wurde : I used to wrote a feature request for requesting a spell checkker for the android mobille app *(I use a bluetooth keyboard, so no spel checkker)* on meta.stackexchange.com. But it was downvoted and deleted beccause poeples were aggainst it. So I can deffinitely tell there is a comunity consensus that spel mistakes should not be corected even beffore writting posts *(except for comments)*.

Comment: Is it even possible to create an autonomous bot that can programmatically correct English grammar, _correctly_?  I thought the general instance of that problem is actually exceedingly difficult to solve.  It might be more appropriate to solve _that_ problem first, and then ask about using it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As [Jeffrey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3614835/jeffrey-bosboom) [mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299123/are-grammarbots-supported#comment219624_299123), I've authored [a userscript](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) with the help of some other Stack Exchange users that aims to accomplish this type of thing; it takes a post and filters through it with a set of regexes that you can modify or add on to. I've been using it for about a year now without any major issues, as the set of corrections I've provided are not too aggressive, and I check my edits before submitting them (the script includes a bit of visual aid in identifying what changes, if any, were made to the post).

I'm not sure what the "official" response on this is<sup>1</sup>, but I think that as long as you are careful and monitor your edits (read: your bot is not autonomous, per se, but rather an "editing assistant"), you'll be fine.

The Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit is intended to be used in this way, and while it will do all of the work for you (fix grammar, usage, and spelling issues, generate an edit summary, etc.) short of actually submitting the edit, it works best when you use it to fix common, repetitive issues while focusing on more pertinent issues specific to a given post. I think that this is a happy medium between automation and personalization, and I would recommend that you use any sort of "GrammarBot" you create in this fashion.

<sub><sup>1</sup> ...and I don't intend to provide one; I just thought I'd give a few recommendations based on my experience in this area.</sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure this thread is asking for stances about autonomous editing bots.

Comment: @Unihedron I understand that, but if the bot is intended to be wholly autonomous (which I don't think is the case here, but I could be wrong), then the answer [isn't as clear](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280554/3366929), and previous discussions disagree on the value and/or legality of bots that operate without human oversight.

Comment: @GrantWinney: From the moment the bots arrived, read our posts, edited and voted, they were doomed. They were undone, destroyed, after all of man's weapons and devices had failed, by the tiniest instances that the Botmaster in his wisdom put upon this earth. By the toll of a billion deaths, man had earned his immunity, his right to survive among the infinite complexities on the [se] network. And that right is ours against all challenges. For neither do men live nor die in vain. Modified from quote by H. G. Wells.

Comment: @AstroCB I think this strikes a balance with what I wanted and was afraid of.

Comment: If it can inline with my viewing a post, make the grammar corrections, then the faster I can assist the person asking the question.

Comment: @GrantWinney Wait, you mean SE posts aren't a regular language?