# Why is the number of daily close votes limited at all?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

As a follow up to my question

- [Regain daily number of close votes from approved question closures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374152/regain-daily-number-of-close-votes-from-approved-question-closures)

where someone answered that there's no approved data that this would have any impact, I am teased to ask:

**Why is the number of daily close votes restricted at all?**

If there's no observable negative or positive effect?

Can someone give me a concise reasoning?

---

Maybe as I am a dupe hammer holder, I should be able to use at least that out of these daily CV contingent restrictions?

---

<sub>Especially in these start semester seasons like present I'm ending up to use all of my close vote contingent of 50 every day, though there are many more close worthy questions come in to the preferred tags I am working with.</sub>

Comment: Well, you have enough rep to be considered a 'trusted user', which means you cannot be trusted:(

Comment: I'm sure there has been a response before that was something along the lines of they intentionally don't want us to spend all our time on here and get exhausted. By having 50 votes, after that there's nothing more you can do. If you had more you could just keep going and going and wear yourself thin. Or something to that effect

Comment: related: [1, 2, 3…test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319131/839601) As on of the active participants in that experiment I can say with certainty that it would be difficult to me to handle more than 50 (generic) close votes. Can't tell whether the same can apply to dupehammer case because it happens in a tag that voter is very well familiar with which is much different from voting in unknown tags

Comment: I seem to recall "fatigue" being a reason given.

Answer (score 55):

Since few users regularly reach the 50 vote cap, there would not be any noticeable impact *except for abuse*. Someone writes a short script and hey, the close queue has 15 million items. Or, 5 people team up to close anything they find uninteresting.

Abuse can be undone and punished, but it's better to have fences before ambulances. In this case, the daily limit is a fence.

Comment: Or a short script + 5 user tokens, effectively closing 15 millions questions. Note that moderators can close as much as they want.

Comment: That doesn't explain why there is a limit for closing, but no limit for editing: imagine a short script for editing millions of posts... oh... I hope Shog9 doesn't see this comment and I hope he doesn't implement the idea to limit editing...

Comment: @Cœur [I cannot see any reason to limit editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284933/918959)

Comment: @Cœur: I actually considered an edit script during [tag:value] burnination. This is unnecessary except for the community owners were being slow of doing the same with their backend driver that doesn't even bump questions.

Comment: @Joshua I do have many wishes for automation myself. Here is one: [Should we fix postimg.org links to postimg.cc?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310325/should-we-fix-postimg-org-links-to-postimg-cc)

Answer (score 14):

It's to control the balance between moderation by the community and by the elected moderation team.

Remember that community moderators are not elected, and the level of reputation required to cast a close vote is pretty easy to come by.  Gold badge hammers require more history, but still would not be immune to being gamed.  Community moderators also aren't receiving the training or participating in discussions held by the moderation team.

If you want more moderation powers (including unlimited or increased close vote count), throw your hat in on the next election.  This gives everyone else on the site a chance to offer you feedback.

While I don't believe that you would be abusive, there are a lot of 10k users on this site that I would not want allowed anywhere near unlimited close (or reopen) voting.

Comment: Note that mods are supposed to be exception handlers, i.e. wading through the garbage and closing everything is not part of their job.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Diamond mods are supposed to take care of what the community *working together* cannot.  Which is very different from empowering individual unelected users to "take out the trash".

Comment: OP's premise seems to be that the community cannot handle the dump of trash that is the start of the semester. Which is a point that can be challenged in itself, but with that premise mods are not a solution.

Comment: Question to voters: Are you expressing disagreement about the facts, or dislike for the policy?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: If there is such a large dump that the community cannot divide and conquer, that is an exception.  I don't think that OP is claiming that the community doesn't have enough close votes to do the job -- just that he personally would like to do more moderation.

Comment: I don'r want to be an elected moderator, since I just want to keep my [tag:c++] lawn clean. Thus your proposal won't apply well for me. Holding the [tag:c++] dupe hammer I am somehow a lownmower for questions within that community but I am still restricted with that overall CV contingent as in contrary for diamond mods who don't necessarily have any experience with the specific tag field.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: And I'm opposed to giving that to anyone purely on the basis of reputation, whether total reputation or tag reputation (gold badge).  I've previously proposed another tier of moderators who don't have all the diamond powers, but are selected on an individual basis and empowered to one-vote close using any of the reasons, not only dupes.  But that idea got shot down.

Comment: No, @AndrasDeak is right. Diamond mods aren't here to close all the things. They don't necessarily have the domain knowledge for that and they can only unilaterally close things. It's actually more complicated to close as a moderator than as a regular user.

Comment: @Catija: I've never said it is the responsibility of a diamond moderator to control the volume of closeable questions.  But if someone wants to close in high volume, they need to go through vetting.