# Daily votes cap for trusted users is just nonsense and doesn't improve anything

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, voting

Again I am asking to remove the daily vote cap for up-/down votes and close votes for trusted users (let's say +10k) of the site.

Besides the vague *"we like to prevent you from exhaustion"* argument, there was never given any resilient data that this would either hurt, or improve the handling of posts here.
I don't feel exhausted, but just bothered when these restrictions come into my way how I am used to handle VLQ posts here. I am doing such stuff sideways while e.g. watching TV series, or other things while still in reach of my keyboard and what's happening in my open browser tabs. Not much source for exhaustion, depression or things like that.

So that restriction is just vain, and just comes into the way for highly trusted users, who try to keep their lawns clean day by day.

Trusted users like me, who are more willing to use their voting capabilities rather than gaining cheap reputation for answering VLQ questions are rarest already, and should be encouraged doing their work and not hindered by those silly daily caps. Especially when there's no resilient observations this would do any harm (particularly experienced SEDE users or CMs prove me wrong, if you can do so).

---

#### Alternative suggestions not involving unlimited votes

Raise the daily voting caps ...

- ... to a fixed limit (let's say ~100, which would cover the need for seasonal (Sep - Feb) waves of VLQ question requests seen at Sunday in particular tags quite well)
- ... seasonally (Sep - Feb) where a recurring rate of VLQ questions is detected
- ... in relation to the actually closed and deleted questions where they've been participating in the process

---

#### Avoiding abuse

There should be a mechanism installed (similar like the currently already running serial voting reversal script), which detects abusive behavior, e.g. done by user scripts or excessively unconcsious voting on questions matching a particular  (language-)tag (e.g. serial duplicate votes for a particular tag).

---

Related requests:

- [Why is the number of daily close votes limited at all?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375579/why-is-the-number-of-daily-close-votes-limited-at-all)
- [Number of upvotes and downvotes allowed should be separate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376226/number-of-upvotes-and-downvotes-allowed-should-be-separate/376231#376231)

---

#### Some more interesting information about the history of that *"cap feature"*

- [But FYI, SO did not originally have voting caps](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1067860516725563392)

  > > But FYI, SO did not originally have voting caps - they were added during the private beta after someone wrote a script to vote on every single post. The reversal of so many votes made a great many people very unhappy.

  -- Shog9

---

#### More background to consider (or even to be improved with resilient statistics)

- Just from my experience and felt VLQ question rate:

  1. We're experiencing a rate of VLQ questions rate every year at the same times, when new school/university semesters start to do their (disregarded, unappreciated and unliked) homeworks (not to mention that most of these users simply missed to read their course textbook again).
  2. These are also periodically seen for certain days of a week, e.g. Sundays, when the homework is due at the following Monday.
  3. There may be more VLQ requests fore a longer time scheme, but most of them are more *"Solve my homework problem plz"* or even worse *"Gimme the codez plz"* kind of questions.

We should simply have a feature to bail out the above mentioned kind of questions unlimited for *topic trusted users* (a *deputy* mode vs a *fully trusted and elected ♦moderator*).

Comment: There is still no evidence that *more* votes would mean *less* bad posts.

Comment: @Makoto Exactly, there's no evidence, so that restriction is vain as I mentioned. Thus there's also no evidence that the restriction improves anything.

Comment: What I'm doing here is torpedoing your argument that having a cap is in vain because there's no evidence to suggest it would hurt.  There's no evidence to suggest that up/down votes being uncapped would *help*, and there is ***firm*** evidence to prove that [more close votes doesn't really change things in a meaningful way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/1079354).

Comment: Users who max out their votes are the stark minority.  Instead of looking at vote count, more effective tooling should be explored since voting is pretty weak by itself.

Comment: @Makoto Well, it would ease and encourage me at least, leaving the overall impact aside :3

Comment: @Makoto: 1) How could there be evidence for something which has not been tried yet? 2) Unless you can provide evidence it does harm, what's the problem removing the cap? Sorry, but your comments rad like "I don't want too much freedom, because I don't need it" to me. 3) Arguments should be countered with arguments, that's what makes a duscussion. You're right, you are using a torpedo, which is hardly an argument, but just disruptive (pun intended).

Comment: @Makoto 4) "Users who max out their votes are the stark minority." - If that means you support giving their votes to users who actively use them, that would be a interesting alternative.

Comment: _There is still no evidence that more votes would mean less bad posts_ is that relevant @makoto? Votes aren’t used to prevent bad posts, they’re used to signal the quality of posts that already exist. More quality indicators can only be a positive thing, yes?

Comment: Great idea, even though it is likely to never change. They don't work on the core Q&A product anymore. Just Jobs and Teams and such. They don't even fix bugs anymore, let alone implement feature requests.

Comment: @Tiny Sad thing yes. But should be easy to fix though.

Comment: I actually feel more exhausted by seeing non closed posts that get answered when they should be closed. I wish we had more votes so that we could help the other moderators. I sometimes could help the other tags, but I need to keep most of my votes for "my" tag. So more votes would mean less duplicates/too broad/typos getting answers, so overall improvement in quality. Not that a lot of people would use them all.

Comment: @TinyGiant shouldn't increasing the maximum number of CV per day be just changing a config setting; if they had designed the product well ;)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I also suspect that would be a simple tweak at the configs. _@NickCraver_ and his co-workers aren't complete idiots for sure.

Comment: or they hardcoded all the values so noone can ever change anything.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well, I mentioned I can't really believe they're that kind of idiots :3 At least not from what I see at twitter.

Comment: Related: *[Why are there voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314)*, *[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899)*, and *[Wikipediholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipediholic)*.

Comment: I think I would oppose this, mostly to avoid the "rich get richer" situation we already have. However, if the purpose of the daily cap is to reduce the likelihood of burnout, then surely your not being exhausted is not evidence that some other people would not be affected by that.

Comment: I agree. The sole reason I don't participate in Triage anymore is because I'd use almost half of my votes before I can even clean up the tags I watch or clean up the CV Queue. Most of the stuff in Triage is Unsalvageable but the people who actually review it think this actually good content. I don't think any of the review queues should use votes at all. I know your post had nothing to do with Triage, but I mention it because it's caused by the same underlying issue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you could candidate to next moderators elections: that could at least solve the close votes limitation for you.

Comment: @halfer that doesn’t matter, you can say that whatever the limit is. Even as it is now, some people will be burning out; doesn’t mean everyone else is affected by that. You can’t stop everyone else having the right tools just because some can’t use them

Comment: @Clive: I am not sure that is the right judgement. If avoiding burn-out is the purpose of the limit, then perhaps there ought to be a balance where it is better to limit some people in order to protect others. In other words, the libertarianism to earn points without negative effect for some folks would come at a heavier cost for others - and as a community it is our job to be concerned about everyone. Still, I am in favour of data-led approaches - I wonder how we could measure burnout as it stands?

Comment: @halfer but at what point does a baseline for that negative affect appear? If some people are burning out at the moment have we not already abandoned them? Both somewhat rhetorical questions I guess, I agree it would be better for this to be somehow data-led

Comment: @Clive: good questions. I did mean to ask a question about burnout some good while ago, but did not get around to it. The paradox is I already spend too much time here, and asking questions on Meta tends to make it worse `;-)`.

Comment: I'm upvoting so we can test ths out.

Comment: For me it's about 50/50: on some days I run *entirely* out of votes, closevotes, and comment votes, and on other days I mentally shut down halfway the day due to the endless list of sub-par questions.

Comment: One of the founding principles for SO was "no unlimited behavior on the Internet" or something. Everything here has a limit. So you have better chances asking to _raise_ the limit.

Comment: Or make the limit progressively increase with reputation. I'm sure it was asked before.

Comment: As pointed out here, without daily limits, voting is open to scripting and thus abuse, how do you answer that? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375581/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands As from the CoC we should assume good intend in 1st place. I am pretty sure abusive voting patterns could be easily detected by the engine, and rolled back (just as with serial voting for a particular user is already done now.)

Comment: @bommelding Technically there is a hard limit on how many requests can be made within a second before rate limiting kicks in, so this still wouldn't violate the "nothing without limits" rule.

Comment: I do not think I ever hit the max cap the 10 years I been here. Issue I have is people who clearly upvote bad questions to get to their max.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Yes, once it was approved it would probably be a five-minute change. Just like adding up-to-date libraries to Stack Snippets. Even those sorts of changes don't happen unless it happens one of the SE staff cares about it.

Comment: Just another data point who often abstains from voting on low-quality content a lot in order to have a few of my precious up/downvotes and close votes left for the tags I particularly care about (and still I do run out, recently on most days).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - **LOL**, they literally updated the list (and added Vue) between yesterday and today (I hadn't seen the update before my comment above). That's just hilarious timing.

Comment: I think the cap might serve one purpose. There's a lot of "meta people" out there, who only do meta tasks on SO. They have mostly dropped their participation on the main site in favour of only doing the meta tasks such as reviewing. In the long term they end up distancing themselves from the main site they are moderating. And so they eventually fail to grasp the community culture and consensus on the main site, where a lot policies are floating and subjective, some changing over time. And they end up forgetting about the most fundamental thing: the technical quality of the content.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed, I would go one step further: meta is a community on its own, it's not very related to SO, nor would it influences operation of the main site. Perhaps the only *actual* impact meta has on SO is some trivial UI layout bug report/fix. We all know feature-request like this one will never be implemented.

Comment: @Lundin The caps of Meta-SO and SO main site could be configured separately. My concerns are about the main site primarily. It's relatively rare that off-topic or VLQ questions are asked at MSO.

Comment: If you vote that many times you are spending way too much time on StackOverflow.  If only your employer knew.

Comment: @Makoto - Neither does calling them "sir". Shame is a security control to use when all else fails. Even the Web Security folks practice it: [Question on Pinning Overrides](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2014Dec/0258.html) on the WebSec mailing list.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I'm only spending my free time here moderating posts. At work I don't do any moderation, just searching as everyone does.

Comment: @Lundin That seems to me like a good argument for limiting *close* votes, but not so much one for limiting downvotes, which to my mind are primarily about the technical quality of the content, and with which roving bands of zealots enforcing their personal version of the rules can do less damage.

Comment: @MarkAmery usually, I don't have enough close votes, I don't downvote when thhe question is unclear, for instance, because it would mean nothing if the question is reopened with good content. But duplicates...

Comment: @jww apparently the one that mail says it did, says he didn't https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2014Dec/0265.html Now, it's an open interpretation what he meant by market pressure. Remember, that people can feel ashamed by a variety of reasons (like every feeling ever).

Comment: I used to hit the vote cap all the time, but i'm a bit more conservative with them now because it really sucks feeling strongly about a particular post and wanting to vote on it, only to be given the "Sorry, you're out of votes." popup. You can of course argue the opinion that that's a good thing, that i should be saving my votes for the posts that need it most... i think that's hogwash.

Comment: @KevinB See my latest updates in the question. I believe there are more considerable points now.

Comment: I like the limit of votes trusted users have, and I wouldn't want it to be changed.