# Rename [gfortran] to [gnu-fortran], and make [gfortran] a synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Recently I came across this question:

[Merge Intel Fortran compiler tags: [ifort], [intel-visual-fortran] and [intel-fortran]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284685/merge-intel-fortran-compiler-tags-ifort-intel-visual-fortran-and-intel-fo/284707#284707)

Here, they renamed [ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifort) into [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran). Essentially, the tag was renamed from `command` into `<vendor/group>-fortran`. Similar tags exist for other vendors, such as [silverfrost-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silverfrost-fortran), [pgi-visual-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgi-visual-fortran), [fujitsu-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fujitsu-fortran), [nag-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nag-fortran).

[gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gfortran) seems a bit the odd duck here as `gfortran` is the name of the binary. So to unify things, I would propose to move [gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gfortran) into [gcc-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-fortran) or [gnu-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-fortran).

Nonetheless, I recognize that most people would tag using [gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gfortran). But the same would hold for [ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifort) and [pgfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgfortran), [f90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f90)... which are tags that don't exist or have been renamed.

Hence, I would propose to reinstate those tags, but directly as a synonym of the tags `<vendor/group>-fortran`

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to tags, we do indeed want the canonical tag to be named in accordance with the actual thing to which it refers. For example, if the language/product/library/API is branded as "Big X Compiler", then we'd want the tag to be named [big-x-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-x-compiler). If it is commonly referred to by its users as "BXC", then we might also have a synonym tag, [bxc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bxc).

I'm also sympathetic to the consistency argument. I've cleaned up countless variants of tags (e.g., SQL Server) to improve consistency. I believe that this makes the site better by making related content easier to find, but even if it doesn't, it makes *me* feel better.

That said, in the case of [gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gfortran), I am not convinced. It looks like GFortran *is* one of the official names of the product, if not *the* official name. Not only does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Fortran) refer to it this way, but [the GCC Wiki entry](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) is entitled "GFortran" and says:

> Gfortran is the name of the GNU Fortran project, developing a free [Fortran 95/2003/2008](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranStandards) compiler for GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection.

It continues to refer to the product as "gfortran" throughout the article. I don't see anywhere where it is called "GNU Fortran" or "GCC Fortran".

Contrast this with [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran), where Intel refers to the product as "Intel Fortran Compiler" or just "Intel Fortran". "IFORT" is merely an abbreviation for that.

If you think it would improve the tagging system, I would be happy to add [gnu-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-fortran) and/or [gcc-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-fortran) as synonyms redirecting to [gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gfortran). But I do not see any cause for renaming the [gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gfortran) tag, since that does appear to be widely used, including by official sources, as the name of the product.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is true the that Wiki entry references gfortran often, however when reading the [Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gfortran/), you notice that they always talk about _GNU Fortran_ and when the word `gfortran` appears, it is always styled as a command. This sort of implies that the GCC-team prefers to use the term GNU Fortran to reference the Fortran compiler suit.