# Should [phalconphp] be a synonym for [phalcon]?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

I just stumbled across a question with both the [phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalcon) and [phalconphp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalconphp) tags.

The two tag wikis look identical, and [phalconphp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalconphp) currently has only 2 views, while [phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalcon) has around 1400 and is 6 years older.

On the other hand, both versions of the tag wiki refer to the framework as "Phalcon**PHP**" in the summary at the top.

I reckon one of them should by a synonym for the other, but having absolutely no expertise in this tag I don't know in which direction, and can't suggest a synonym in the tag wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This merge is clearly appropriate. Of all the questions having the [phalconphp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalconphp) tag, only a small number did not also have the [phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalcon) tag, and even those were all clearly related to this PHP framework. After purging a couple of questions that lacked sufficient information to answer, I merged [phalconphp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalconphp) into [phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalcon) and created a synonym mapping between the two.

As for which nomenclature should be used on the "canonical" tag, it seems to me that the product is named "Phalcon". That's what I find on [the official website](https://phalcon.io/en-us), where it is either referred to simply as "Phalcon" or the "Phalcon PHP Library", but never "PhalconPHP" or "Phalcon-PHP". In fact, I see no evidence *anywhere* that the framework is called "Phalcon**PHP**", as you claimin the question. The [documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/installation) uses "Phalcon" throughout, as does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalcon_(framework)). The official Twitter account is @phalconphp, but presumably that's because @phalcon was already taken. On the Twitter bio and elsewhere, it is never referred to as "PhalconPHP". Thus, for now, I'm leaving [phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalcon) as the "canonical" tag. If a PHP domain expert wants to suggest alternatives, I'm all ears, of course.

Comment: It was referred to as "PhalconPHP" in the tag wiki itself. In the summary at the top, at least.

Comment: Ah, that...doesn't really matter. :-) The tag wiki here on Stack Overflow is created by the community (anyone can suggest edits to it), and therefore should not be used as evidence of official usage. For tag naming, we really prefer to use the actual/official name of the product, as I recently discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392947).