# Synonymize [intel-ifort] and [intel-fortran]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have tags to support various implementations for Fortran compilers, libraries, tools and such.  For Intel Fortran a little while ago we [tidied up tags to settle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284685/3157076) on [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran) and this now has 700+ questions a suitable wiki/wiki excerpt.

Recently we've seen [intel-ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-ifort) repeatedly pop up. "ifort" is the name of the compiler component of the Intel Fortran universe, so this tag's emergence is not too surprising. However, tag fragmentation is bad enough in the Fortran world here.

Can we [please make](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-fortran/synonyms) [intel-ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-ifort) a synonym of [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran) (the main tag)?

Recent examples:

- [2021-05-04](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67216559/3)
- [2021-05-03](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67367668/2)
- [A proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28886132)

Comment: Upvoted the synonym suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-fortran/synonyms - apparently I have enough rep in intel-fortran for some reason. :P